# How to display a JSON representation and not [Object Object] on the screen

Tags: json, angular

I am making an AngularJS 2 application with the beta version. I want to show a JSON representation of an object in my page, but it shows `[Object Object]` and not  `{key1:value1 ....}`

From the component I can use:

```
get example() {return JSON.stringify(this.myObject)};
```

and then in the template:

```
{{example}}
```

but if I have an array of objects and would like to print a list of these objects, how I can do it?

Using:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#obj of myArray">{{obj}}</li>
</ul>
```

results in something like:

```
- [Object Object]
- [Object Object]
- [Object Object]
- [Object Object]
```

and so on. Is there a way to display those as JSON?

Answer (score 224):

If you want to see what you you have inside an object in your web app, then use the *json pipe* in a component HTML template, for example:

```
<li *ngFor="let obj of myArray">{{obj | json}}</li>
```

**Tested and valid using Angular 4.3.2.**

Comment: Thank you, the json pile was I need...from angular 1 something changed :)

Comment: @foralobo Json Pipe was available in Angular 1 as well ;)

Answer (score 92):

We can use angular pipe **json**

```
{{ jsonObject | json }}
```

Answer (score 49):

**To loop through JSON Object : In Angluar's (6.0.0+), now they provide the pipe `keyvalue` :**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object| keyvalue">
  {{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}
</div>
```

**[DO READ ALSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699937/2349407)**

**To just display JSON**

```
{{ object | json }}
```

Comment: Fav answer because it has both, and you'll likely need both: "just json" for simple variables. But for anything like a form control that has circular references, you'll need the loop presented as the first option. Both are still correct syntax in Angular9.

Answer (score 12):

Dumping object content as JSON can be achieved without using `ngFor`. Example:

**Object**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public theObject: any = {
        simpleProp: 1,
        complexProp: {
            InnerProp1: "test1",
            InnerProp2: "test2"
        },
        arrayProp: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
```

**Markup**

```
<div [innerHTML]="theObject | json"></div>
```

**Output** (ran through a beautifier for better readability, otherwise it is output in a single row)

```
{
  "simpleProp": 1,
  "complexProp": {
    "InnerProp1": "test1",
    "InnerProp2": "test2"
  },
  "arrayProp": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```

---

I have also discovered a JSON formatter and viewer that displays larger JSON data more readable (similar to JSONView Chrome extension): https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-json-viewer

```
<ngx-json-viewer [json]="someObject" [expanded]="false"></ngx-json-viewer>
```

Comment: Also, if you change from div to pre tag you get it properly formated automatically.

Comment: @Oddleif - yes. I have also added a reference to a very useful viewer that should display the information more conveniently.

Answer (score 6):

```
<li *ngFor="let obj of myArray">{{obj | json}}</li>
```

Comment: The same is already answered, and you must use a let keyword before obj in *ngFor loop.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways in which you can get the values:-

1. Access the property of the object using dot notation (obj.property) .
2. Access the property of the object by passing in key value for example obj["property"]

Answer (score 2):

Updating others' answers with the new syntax:

```
<li *ngFor="let obj of myArray">{{obj | json}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.http.get<any>('http://192.168.1.15:4000/GetPriority')
  .subscribe(response => 
  {
  this.records=JSON.stringify(response) // impoprtant
  console.log("records"+this.records)
  });
```

Comment: Hey, to improve on what you wrote, you could add some explanation to your answer to make sure that a reader who is not very familiar with the concepts can understand your decisions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have array of object and you  would like to deserialize them in compoent

```
get example() { this.arrayOfObject.map(i => JSON.stringify (i) ) };
```

then in template

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="obj of example">{{obj}}</li>
</ul>
```