# I want show the response dynamically in Angular8

Tags: json, angular

Here is JSON data i need to bind this data to Html page controls like label and textboxes.
i need to bind all values dynamically in angular. do you guys any thougts. please help me.

```
  {
      "model": "abcd.abilivcdcty.configuration",
      "typeId": "abcd.edge.modules.opcuamodule.configuration",
      "baseTypes": [
        "abcd.ia.edge.module.configuration@1.0.0"
      ],
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "unique": [
        "name"
      ],
```

here prporties static word and it should as label and remaining like name and value should shown as dynamic.

```
},
"abilityConfiguration": {
  "useRestEndpoint": {
    "dataType": "boolean",
    "value": true
  },


  "associatedEndpoints": {
    "dataType": "array",
    "items": "string"
  }
},
"uaApplicationConfiguration": {
  "applicationName": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "ABCD.IA.Edge.UaModule"
  },
  "applicationUri": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "urn:abcd:ia:edge:UaModule"
  },
  "productUri": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "http://abbcd.com/Ia/Edge/UaModule/"
  },
  "applicationType": {
    "dataType": "integer",
    "value": 1
  },
  "securityConfiguration": {
    "connectionMode": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "None"
    },
    "securityLevel": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 0
    },
    "userIdentityType": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "Anonymous"
    },
    "applicationCertificate": {
      "storeType": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "Directory"
      },
      "storePath": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "./OPC Foundation/PKI/own"
      },

    },
    "trustedIssuerCertificates": {
      "StoreType": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "Directory"
      },
      "storePath": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "./OPC Foundation/PKI/issuer"
      }
    },
    "trustedPeerCertificates": {
      "storeType": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "Directory"
      },
      "storePath": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "./OPC Foundation/PKI/trusted"
      }
    },
    "rejectedCertificateStore": {
      "storeType": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "Directory"
      },
      "storePath": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "./OPC Foundation/PKI/rejected"
      }
    },
    "autoAcceptUntrustedCertificates": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "nonceLength": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 32
    },
    "addAppCertToTrustedStore": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "rejectSHA1SignedCertificates": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "minimumCertificateKeySize": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 2048
    }
  },
  "transportQuotas": {
    "OperationTimeout": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 120000
    },
    "maxStringLength": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 1048576
    },
    "maxByteStringLength": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 4194304
    },
    "maxArrayLength": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 65535
    },
    "maxMessageSize": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 4194304
    },

  "clientConfiguration": {
    "hdaDataStoragePath": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "string"
    },
    "metadataStoragePath": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "/opcua/metadata"
    },
    "useDnsNameAndPortFromDiscoveryUrl": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "useSecureConnection": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "None"
    },
    "reconnectInterval": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 5000
    },
    "allNodeBrowseAtConnect": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "daReadConfig": {
      "readInterval": {
        "dataType": "integer",
        "value": 1000
      },
      "usingSubscription": {
        "dataType": "boolean",
        "value": true
      }
    },

    "hdaNodesToRead": {
      "description": "Node details are provides that to be subscribed",
      "dataType": "array",
      "items": "string",
      "value": [
        "ns=2;s=AlternatingBoolean",
        "ns=2;s=DipData",
        "ns=2;s=NegativeTrendData",
        "ns=2;s=PositiveTrendData",
        "ns=2;s=RandomSignedInt32",
        "ns=2;s=RandomUnsignedInt32",
        "ns=2;s=SpikeData",
        "ns=2;s=StepUp",
        "ns=3;s=Furnace1.State",
        "ns=3;s=Furnace1.Temperature",
        "ns=3;s=Furnace1.TemperatureSetPoint"
      ]
    },
    "hdaReadConfig": {
      "from": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "2012-01-022"
      },
      "to": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "2012-02-11"
      },
      "frequency": {
        "dataType": "string",
        "value": "2"
      }
    },
    "generateMetaData": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "defaultSessionTimeout": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 600000
    },
    "minSubscriptionLifetime": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 10000
    }
  },
  "traceConfiguration": {
    "outputFilePath": {
      "dataType": "string",
      "value": "./ABcd.Edgeasd.UaModule.log.txt"
    },
    "deleteOnLoad": {
      "dataType": "boolean",
      "value": true
    },
    "traceMasks": {
      "dataType": "integer",
      "value": 0
    }
  },
  "disableHiResClock": {
    "dataType": "boolean",
    "value": true
  }
},
"rabbitMqConfiguration": {
  "hostIpAddress": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "124.123.134"
  },
  "userName": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "abcd-admin"
  },
  "password": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "abcd1234"
  },
  "virtualHostAddress": {
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "/"
  }
},
"docker": {
  "env": {
    "value": {
      "telemetryConfiguration__enabled": {
        "value": "true"
      },
      "edgeModuleConfiguration__communicationTimeout": {
        "value": "00:01:00"
      },
      "edgeModuleConfiguration__keepAlivePeriod": {
        "value": "00:01:30"
      },
      "log_level": {
        "value": "Information"
      },
      "storageConfiguration__storagePath": {
        "value": "/files"
      }
    }
  },
  "image": {
    "value": "abcd.azurecr.io/abcd.abasdkajs.device.edge.dias.opcclclc:1.0.3"
  }
}
```

},
  "isDeleted": false
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn the basics of Angular
2. You can use the Angular `FormsModule` to present data in a form. Or use the `{{ 'some data' }}`notation in the template to display some json data.

Some useful links:

- https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data
- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax
- https://angular.io/guide/user-input
- https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview
- [How to display a JSON representation and not [Object Object] on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864184/how-to-display-a-json-representation-and-not-object-object-on-the-screen)

Comment: Hi Ling, Actually my requirement is whatever response is coming from service. everything need bind dynmically. means. here i should use only one Textbox and and label.?

Comment: Did you red my links? They should meet your requirements. Especially the first one