# access key and value of object using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I am a bit confused about how to get the `key` and `value` of an object in angular2 while using `*ngFor` for iterating over the object. I know in angular 1.x there is a syntax like

```html
ng-repeat="(key, value) in demo"
```

but I don't know how to do the same in angular2. I have tried something similar, without success:

```html
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor='#key of demo'>{{key}}</li>
    </ul>

    demo = {
        'key1': [{'key11':'value11'}, {'key12':'value12'}],
        'key2': [{'key21':'value21'}, {'key22':'value22'}],
      }
```

Here is a plnkr with my attempt:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mIj619FncOpfdwrR0KeG?p=preview

How can I get `key1` and `key2` dynamically using `*ngFor`? After searching extensively, I found the idea of using pipes but I don't know how to go about it.
Is there any inbuilt pipe for doing the same in angular2?

Comment: currently there is not support `key, value` pair kind of syntax in angular2 `ngFor`, you should look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31490713/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah already read this answer. any alternate for now ?

Comment: @Pradeep I don't think of any other way for this now, you should go for creating own `Pipe` for this..

Comment: hmm but i have no idea how to create pipe for the same.

Comment: @Pradeep answer which I gave you for reference, has that implementation. they should work..

Comment: no i tried the the answer with max upvote but did't run that pipe

Comment: Cool.. I'll look at plunkr once i have access to machine..

Comment: Am I the only one to be surprised there is no easier way to do this in 2017?

Comment: this.keys = Object.keys(this.demo)

Comment: I've object inside that value. How to acces it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74827855/6666348

Answer (score 844, accepted):

As in **latest release of Angular (v6.1.0)** , Angular Team has added new built in pipe for the same named as `keyvalue` pipe to help you iterate through objects, maps, and arrays, in the `common` module of angular package.
For example -

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of testObject | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

To keep original order, use `keyvalue:onCompare`,
and in component define callback:

```
// ...
import {KeyValue} from '@angular/common';

@Component(/* ... */)
export class MyComponent {
  private onCompare(_left: KeyValue<any, any>, _right: KeyValue<any, any>): number {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

## [Working Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

check it out here for more useful information -

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-3
- https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/2b49bf7

If you are using Angular v5 or below or you want to achieve using pipe follow this answer

- [access key and value of object using ngfor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536052/5043867)

Comment: lol I had to do an ng6 update just to access this pipe - great stuff - thx

Comment: You can keep the original key order using a custom comparator:  
`*ngFor="let item of testObject | keyvalue:keepOriginalOrder"`  
and in your class define:  
`public keepOriginalOrder = (a, b) => a.key`

Comment: this should be the answer - working well on angular 7

Comment: So the reason I'm here is because Canada decided to give their Provinces with two-letter abbreviations and the written order vs Province abbreviation for Northwest Territories (NT) and Nova Scotia (NS) don't line up. "Nor" comes before "Nov", but NS comes before NT.

Comment: hi @PardeepJain do you have an answer for this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66395350/angular-keyvalue-pipe-not-working-on-string-number-enum

Comment: @mike-shtil that comment was lit! thanks man that is exactly what I needed but worried if it is impacting performance as looping twice

Comment: For simple : https://plnkr.co/edit/fTh6zerwbf06EhdZ?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: What if {{item.value}} is again object? How to access its values?

Comment: this answer work on angular 13, thank you

Comment: @pera you can do inner ngFor, like this: `ngFor="let element of item.value`

Answer (score 453):

Have `Object.keys` accessible in the template and use it in `*ngFor`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myview',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(items)">{{key + ' : ' + items[key]}}</div>`
})

export class MyComponent {
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  items = { keyOne: 'value 1', keyTwo: 'value 2', keyThree: 'value 3' };
  constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: @PardeepJain it's an ES5 method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @tomtastico How would you display this for a 3D array? For example {"1": {"1.1": ["1.1.1","1.1.2"]}}. And then nesting 3 ngFor's

Comment: @Frank you just said it yourself. Nest the `*ngFor`s. First two using `objectKeys`, innermost no need (as it's just an array).

Comment: Though [recall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537666/1028230): "*Maps have no orders in keys and hence their iteration is unpredictable.*" You should probably sort the keys in `objectKeys` to make the sticklers happy. ;^) Pretty sure the [new pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24319) does.

Comment: Awesome. Setting objectKeys = Object.keys is simplest method I've seen to be able to check the length of an object from the HTML.

Comment: While it works, I get this error in Visual Code: "Member 'objectKeys' is not callable Angular"

Answer (score 248):

You could create a custom pipe to return the list of key for each element.
Something like that:

```ts
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let c of content">           
  <td *ngFor="let key of c | keys">{{key}}: {{c[key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Edit**

You could also return an entry containing both key and value:

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```html
<span *ngFor="let entry of content | keys">           
  Key: {{entry.key}}, value: {{entry.value}}
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean regarding async? Perhaps its use in my answer is ambiguous. The pipe doesn't need it. You can use pipe if the object you want to iterate over is an observable...

Comment: Thanks! Also, Good explanation here, check this - How to use Pipes!   
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angular-2-let-s-talk-about-pipes-ng-filter-in-angular-1-f46319edaf73#.fw9qvebjv

Comment: note the missing closing bracket in `keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);`

Comment: I actually discourage anyone from using pipes to create collections inside `*ngFor` expression. It creates huge performance bottleneck because it needs to generate the collection every time the change detector checks for changes.

Comment: Thanks for the solution...the problem is that whenever the object changes, the pipe doesn't update. If I add `pure:false` to the pipe, it becomes very inefficient. Do you have a solution to update the pipe manually whenever I change the object (remove item)?

Comment: Lovely answer Thierry. What changes do I need to make to make it work for an `object array` like [{"animal":"dog", "country":"france", "car":"nano"}]

Comment: Thanks! You can add a first `ngFor` to iterate over the array and put the `ngFor` with the pipe in it... Hope it answers your question!

Comment: The answer is a little bit outdated. The line *ngFor="#entry of content | keys" doesn't work properly and the for ... in loop better to change to "for (const key of Object.keys(value)) "

Comment: `ngFor` has been removed. Need to change to `ngForOf`.
`<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="content" let-c="">
<tr>{{c}}</tr>
</ng-template>`

Comment: @RachChen Not in templates: `common: NgFor has been removed as it was deprecated since v4. Use NgForOf instead. This does not impact the use of*ngFor in your templates.` (https://jaxenter.com/road-to-angular-5-133253.html)

Comment: @martin Would that actually be such a performance loss when using just `Object.keys()` to retrieve the keys within the pipe?

Comment: You should use keys.unshift(...) instead of keys.push(...), this will preserve the order of the keys in the loop.

Answer (score 70):

### Update

In **6.1.0-beta.1** **KeyValuePipe** was introduced https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24319

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of {'b': 1, 'a': 1} | keyvalue">
  {{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eIfgvtsd66ztkDN2Xzio?p=preview)**

### Previous version

Another approach is to create `NgForIn` directive that will be used like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let key in obj">
   <b>{{ key }}</b>: {{ obj[key] }}
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6tDTIfl14chTOJfEzKbr?p=preview)**

**ngforin.directive.ts**

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFor][ngForIn]'
})
export class NgForIn<T> extends NgForOf<T> implements OnChanges {

  @Input() ngForIn: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: NgForInChanges): void {
    if (changes.ngForIn) {
      this.ngForOf = Object.keys(this.ngForIn) as Array<any>;

      const change = changes.ngForIn;
      const currentValue = Object.keys(change.currentValue);
      const previousValue = change.previousValue ? Object.keys(change.previousValue) : undefined;
      changes.ngForOf =  new SimpleChange(previousValue, currentValue, change.firstChange);

      super.ngOnChanges(changes);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 53):

From Angular 6.1 you can use the *keyvalue* pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testObject | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

But it has the inconvenient that sorts the resulting list by the key value.
If you need something neutral:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keyValueUnsorted', pure: false  })
export class KeyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: any): any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in input) {
      if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push({ key: key, value: input[key]});
      }
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to specify the *pure:false* pipe attribute. In this case, the pipe is invoked on each change-detection cycle, even if the input reference has not changed (so is the case when you add properties to an object).

Comment: Already shared the same answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491848/5043867

Comment: @PardeepJain please let other people share as well :) ! second part of answer is what I needed

Comment: @minigeek different solutions are always welcome mate. But when I have posted the comment this second part you referring was missing and only first part is there  which is duplucate of accepted answer. you can check changelog of answer history.

Comment: @PardeepJain. Yes your answer and that guy's comment only helped me fix thing. I understand ur point how plagiarism feels :p

Answer (score 28):

Elaboration of @Thierry's answer with example.

There is no inbuilt pipe or method to get `key and value` from the *ngFor loop. so we have to create custom pipe for the same. as thierry said here is the answer with code.

** The pipe class implements the PipeTransform interface's transform method that takes an input value and an optional array of parameter strings and returns the transformed value.

** The transform method is essential to a pipe. The PipeTransform interface defines that method and guides both tooling and the compiler. It is optional; Angular looks for and executes the transform method regardless.
for more info regards pipe [refer here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

```
import {Component, Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [KeysPipe]
})
export class AppComponent { 

  demo = {
    'key1': 'ANGULAR 2',
    'key2': 'Pardeep',
    'key3': 'Jain',
  }
}


@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and HTML part is:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='#key of demo | keys'>
   Key: {{key.key}}, value: {{key.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/50LlK0k6OnMnkc2kNHM2?p=preview

## update to RC

as suggested by user6123723(thanks) in comment here is  update.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let key of demo | keys'>
   Key: {{key.key}}, value: {{key.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This needs to be updated: Here's the warning I get "#" inside of expressions is deprecated. Use "let" instead! ("
</li>-->
<ul *ngIf="demo">
  <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor='#key of demo| keys'>
   Key: {{key.key}}, value: {{key.value}}
  </li>
"): myComponent@56:6

Comment: Not sure if this is new, but to cite from the docs:
> We must include our pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.

Answer (score 20):

@Marton had an **important objection to the accepted answer** on the grounds that the pipe creates a new collection on each change detection. I would instead create an HtmlService which provides a range of utility functions which the view can use as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myview',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let i of html.keys(items)">{{i + ' : ' + items[i]}}</div>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  items = {keyOne: 'value 1', keyTwo: 'value 2', keyThree: 'value 3'};
  constructor(private html: HtmlService){}
}

@Injectable()
export class HtmlService {
  keys(object: {}) {
    return Object.keys(object);
  }
  // ... other useful methods not available inside html, like isObject(), isArray(), findInArray(), and others...
}
```

Comment: and how is that better than just `Object.keys(...)` inside the *ngFor?

Comment: Because it will throw: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined`. It doesn't seem to be supported in the template.

Comment: This works very well as a solution and avoids the performance issues pointed out above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor/39896058#comment66192984_35536052

Comment: hello, can this b used not in the `template` option, but in the template's actual html code? thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you're already using Lodash, you can do this simple approach which includes both key and value:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let key of _.keys(demo)'>{{key}}: {{demo[key]}}</li>
</ul>
```

In the typescript file, include:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

and in the exported component, include:

```
_: any = _;
```

Comment: sorry but no need to use extra library like Lodash for such things. anyways new methods are always welcome :)

Answer (score 13):

Thought of adding an answer for Angular 8:

For looping you can do:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of BATCH_FILE_HEADERS | keyvalue: keepOriginalOrder">
   <th nxHeaderCell>{{'upload.bulk.headings.'+item.key |translate}}</th>
</ng-container>
```

Also if you need the above array to keep the original order then declare this inside your class:

```
public keepOriginalOrder = (a, b) => a.key;
```

Comment: Would be great if you add working example as well, stackblitz may be

Comment: @PardeepJain, I would for far more complex ones.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the pipe but i had to make some changes before i could use it in angular 2 RC5. Changed the Pipe import line and also added type of any to the keys array initialization.

```
 import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({name: 'keys'})
 export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value) {
   let keys:any = [];
   for (let key in value) {
      keys.push( {key: key, value: value[key]} );
    }
     return keys;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah imports has been changed

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `keyvalue` pipe as the sample code is provided:

```
    <div style="flex-direction: column">
        <app-cart-item
            class="cart-item"
            *ngFor="let keyValuePair of this.allProductRecords | keyvalue"
            [productRecord]="keyValuePair.value"
            (removeProduct)="removeProductFromCart(keyValuePair.key)"
        ></app-cart-item>
        <br />
        <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bolder">
            Total ${{ getTotalPurchaseAmount() }}
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers here worked for me out of the box, here is what worked for me:

Create `pipes/keys.ts` with contents:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value:any, args:string[]): any {
        let keys:any[] = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

Add to `app.module.ts` (Your main module):

```
import { KeysPipe } from './pipes/keys';
```

and then add to your module declarations array something like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        KeysPipe
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your view template you can use something like this:

```
<option *ngFor="let entry of (myData | keys)" value="{{ entry.key }}">{{ entry.value }}</option>
```

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) is a good reference I found if you want to read more.

Comment: may i know what is the difference betwee your answer and other answer's (using pipe only) provided above ? it seems same as above

Comment: Sure
1. The examples above uses *ngFor="#entry" instead of *ngFor="let entry of" and my compiler didn't accept the #entry syntax, the reference doesn't use # either. "let entry of (myData | keys)" seems to be a better solution.

2. My compiler didn't validate the example Pipe Class either because it was missing explicit data types so I added that.

3. The examples above doesn't show how to integrate the Pipe into a project which my answer does, you need to import it into the main module.

Comment: haha yes offcourese, because when answer was given at that time syntax including `#` etc. btw your answer is also correct no doubt

Answer (score 7):

Use index:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of Objects; index as key">
```

Usage:

```
{{key}} -> {{value}}
```

Comment: That is something new to me, Better If you could add example along with your answer :) Also can you point me to any documentation for the same?

Comment: What is the type of Objects ? Array or Map? Please make it clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this example, the "key"  is the index. This have nothing to do with the question and wont work to access the real key

Answer (score 6):

There's a real nice library that does this among other nice pipes. It's called [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#object).

For example, keys pipe returns keys for an object, and values pipe returns values for an object:

**keys pipe**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of {foo: 1, bar: 2} | keys">{{key}}</div> 
<!-- Output: 'foo' and 'bar -->
```

**values pipe**

```
<div *ngFor="let value of {foo: 1, bar: 2} | values">{{value}}</div>
<!-- Output: 1 and 2 -->
```

No need to create your own custom pipe :)

Comment: good alternate, but thing is why to use external library for simple peace of code if we can do this using simple piece of code like pipe

Comment: Umm... but it is a pipe? It's just one line in your package.json and another two lines in your module when you import the library. On the other hand, a custom pipe needs a separate file with some 10-20 lines of code and also the import lines in your module. We find using ngx-pipes very easy in our projects. Why should we reinvent the wheel? :)

Comment: yeah no doubt, actually its an opinion based, you can choose either between these two, no one is wrong way.

Comment: Don't forget, if you write a custom pipe, you must test that custom pipe *as well*. So that's 10-20 lines of pipe code, and then probably 20-40 lines of test code to test the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple solution

You can use typescript iterators for this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
declare var Symbol;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`<div>
    <h4>Iterating an Object using Typescript Symbol</h4><br>
Object is : <p>{{obj | json}}</p>
</div>
============================<br>
Iterated object params are:
<div *ngFor="#o of obj">
{{o}}
</div>

`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public obj: any = {
    "type1": ["A1", "A2", "A3","A4"],
    "type2": ["B1"],
    "type3": ["C1"],
    "type4": ["D1","D2"]
  };

  constructor() {
    this.obj[Symbol.iterator] =  () => {
          let i =0;

          return {
            next: () => {
              i++;
              return {
                  done: i > 4?true:false,
                  value: this.obj['type'+i]
              }
            }
          }
    };
  }
}
```

> http://plnkr.co/edit/GpmX8g?p=info

Answer (score 3):

change demo type to array 
or iterate over your object and push to another array

```
public details =[];   
Object.keys(demo).forEach(key => {
      this.details.push({"key":key,"value":demo[key]);
    });
```

and from html:

```
<div *ngFor="obj of details">
  <p>{{obj.key}}</p>
  <p>{{obj.value}}</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a appropriate method, this can be easily done by anyone.

Answer (score 3):

## ECMA 2017+ solution

Following the idea of some other answers, you can create a Pipe to **create an array of `[key, value]` from your object**, but in a much simpler way, following the new method [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) introduced in the [ECMA 2017](https://262.ecma-international.org/8.0/).

### Pipe

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Transform a literal object into array
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'forObject',
  pure: true,
})
export class ForObjectPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(object, args?: any): any {
    return Object.entries(object);
  }
}
```

### Module

In your module, you declare and provide it

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ForObjectPipe } from './for-object.pipe';

import { MyPageRoutingModule } from './my-routing.module';
import { MyPage } from './my.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyPage,
    ForObjectPipe,
  ],
  providers: [
    ForObjectPipe,
  ]
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

Then you can use in your component typescript code or HTML.

### Using in component

```
// ...
import { ForObjectPipe } from './for-object.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.page.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
  obj: { [key: any]: any } = {
    1: 'hello',
    2: 'world',
  };

  constructor(private forObjectPipe: ForObjectPipe) { }

  foo() {
     const myArray = this.forObjectPipe.transform(this.obj);
     // same as 
     const myArray = Object.entries(this.obj);
  }
}
```

### Using in component view

```html
<h1>Object:</h1>
<div *ngFor="let pair of obj | forObject">
  KEY: {{ pair[0] }} - VALUE: {{ pair[1] }}
</div>
```

Output:

```
Object:
KEY: 1 - VALUE: hello
KEY: 2 - VALUE: world
```

Live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qapapx?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: This does not answer the question! return Object.values(object); will give a list of values and not the key, values as asked.

Comment: Sorry, @Bill.  I changed the method to return the key-value pair instead of only the values. Instead of using `Object.values`, you can use `Object.entries`.   Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I think Object.keys is the best solution to this problem. For anyone that comes across this answer and is trying to find out why Object.keys is giving them ['0', '1'] instead of ['key1', 'key2'], a cautionary tale - beware the difference between "of" and "in":

I was already using Object.keys, something similar to this:

```ts
interface demo {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}

createDemo(mydemo: any): Array<demo> {
    const tempdemo: Array<demo> = [];

    // Caution: use "of" and not "in"
    for (const key of Object.keys(mydemo)) {
        tempdemo.push(
            { key: key, value: mydemo[key]}
        );
    }

    return tempdemo;
}
```

However, instead of

```
for (const key OF Object.keys(mydemo)) {
```

I had inadvertently wrote

```
for (const key IN Object.keys(mydemo)) {
```

which "worked" perfectly fine without any error and returned

```
[{key: '0', value: undefined}, {key: '1', value: undefined}]
```

That cost me about 2 hours googling and cursing..

*(slaps forehead)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this for now, i know not very efficient as you don't want to convert the object you receive from firebase.

```
    this.af.database.list('/data/' + this.base64Email).subscribe(years => {
        years.forEach(year => {

            var localYears = [];

            Object.keys(year).forEach(month => {
                localYears.push(year[month])
            });

            year.months = localYears;

        })

        this.years = years;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get **dynamic object's key** with by trying this

```
myObj['key']
```

Comment: are you serious?

Answer (score -3):

Create your array like this

```
tags = [
        {
            name : 'Aliko Dogara',
            amount   : '60,000',
            purpose: 'Office repairs'
        },
        {
            name : 'Aliko Dogara',
            amount   : '60,000',
            purpose: 'Office repairs'
        },
        {
            name : 'Aliko Dogara',
            amount   : '60,000',
            purpose: 'Office repairs'
        },
        {
            name : 'Aliko Dogara',
            amount   : '60,000',
            purpose: 'Office repairs'
        },
        {
            name : 'Aliko Dogara',
            amount   : '60,000',
            purpose: 'Office repairs'
        }
    ];
```

works all the time