# How to display json object using *ngFor

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

I want to display the below data from Firebase

```
{
   "-KBN9O_qqz-nZ9tPWFdM":{
      "createdAt":1456399292790,
      "isActive":true,
      "name":"Hero 1"
   },
   "-KBN9gjJw1ZlMgt9pVsl":{
      "createdAt":1456399371220,
      "isActive":true,
      "name":"Hero 2"
   },
   "-KBN9hYI4vYAsyh5k1lX":{
      "createdAt":1456399374548,
      "isActive":true,
      "name":"Hero 3"
   }
}
```

when doing [angular.io Tour of Heroes](http://angular.io) tutorial for example

```
<li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

So hero id should show for example `-KBN9hYI4vYAsyh5k1lX`
and hero name should show for example `hero 3`

---

I have done some research and come across this stackoverflow solution by @Thierry Templier [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

(1) Is this the right solution to my problem?

(2) Is there a simpler solution to this problem because I feel that it would be really common for developers using Angular2 to display such json data.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35540129/5043867

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to implement a custom pipe to do this. `ngFor` only supports array and not object.

This pipe will look like that:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
<span *ngFor="#entry of content | keys">           
  Key: {{entry.key}}, value: {{entry.value}}
</span>
```

See this question for more details:

- [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor/35536052#35536052)

Comment: Hi Thierry, is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Good explanation here, check this - How to use Pipes:   
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angular-2-let-s-talk-about-pipes-ng-filter-in-angular-1-f46319edaf73#.fw9qvebjv

Comment: `Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
  if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys = [...keys, { key, value: value[key] }];
  }
});`

Comment: No need to check for .hasOwnProperty since Object.keys() returns own properties. The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

Comment: This works for Angular5 without the `#`.
You can also add a search filter with `<input [(ngModel)]="term">` and `*ngFor="#entry of content | keys | filter:term"`.
Further you can search multiple properties with `keys.push({key: 'key'+'value[key].prop', value: value[key]})`.

Answer (score 9):

You can put the keys in an array and ng-repeat the keys.

```
export class IterateOverObject {
    public arrayOfKeys;

    @Input heros;
    constructor() {
        this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.heros);
    }
}

<li *ngFor="#key of arrayOfKeys">
  <span class="badge">{{key}}</span> {{heros[key].name}}
</li>
```

This looks simple to me.. More info is [here](https://webcake.co/object-properties-in-angular-2s-ngfor/)

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 4):

Firebase id is called *$.key*.
Also, # is now changed to *let*.
This would work for you:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <span class="badge">{{hero.$key}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular did support **KeyValuePipe** from version **6.1**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'keyvalue-pipe',
  template: `<span>
    <p>Object</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
    <p>Map</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
  </span>`
})
export class KeyValuePipeComponent {
  object: {[key: number]: string} = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
  map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
}
```

More info: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe