# Deep nested json to array in array / json rendering of Angular 2 *ngFor

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I want to list states and types of the following json with angular 2 *ngFor. The parental properties also should be rendered.

```
var test= {
  '192-168-0-16':{
    'ac395516-96d0-4533-8e0e-efbc68190e':{
      'state':  "none",
      'typ': "test"
    },
    'ac395516-96d0-4533-8e0e-efbc68190e':{
      'state':  "none",
      'typ':  "dummy"
    }
  },
  '222-21-12-12': {
    'ac395516-96d0-4533-8e0e-efbc68190e': {
      'state': "none",
      'typ': "none"
    }
  }
```

Angular 2:

```
<div *ngFor='#s of test'> <!-- also other properties should be visible -->
   <div *ngFor='#t of s'>
      {{t.state}} {{t.typ}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Of course this does not work. Is it possible without many data transforms? I am not sure how to get arrays of arrays of my json.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in your case? Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use array with `ngFor`. If you want to use objects at this level, you should consider to use a custom pipe.

See this answer for more details:

- [How to display json object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647365/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor/35647396#35647396)

Based on this, I would refactor your code this way:

```
<div *ngFor='#s of (test | keyValues)'>
  <div *ngFor='#t of (s.value | keyValues)'>
   {{t.value.state}} {{t.value.typ}}
  </div>
</div>
```

with the following pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keyValues'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thierry Can you please Explain why we did {key: key, value: value[key]} . i understand key:key but why the second parameter

Comment: and it only displays none none when running the code , Can you please help on this @thierry