# Nested arrays/objects using NgFor

Tags: angular

I'm creating a scheduler/calendar, but I have to built my own from scratch.

I have an array of days per month. For example May: 31 days.
Now I want to seperate that array into weeks, and then display using a table. (like a calendar)

Please take into consideration that later on, I will have to make these 'days' clickable to be able to perform further actions on them.

**What I tried:**

I tried to do a nested array weeks[week_number][day_number].
However when trying to show the days the following code does not work at all. It shows nothing.

```
<tr *ngFor="let week of weeks; let i = index">
<td *ngFor="let day of week.days; let j = index "> {{ day }}</td>
```

I have looked up StackOverflow but could not find anything.

Comment: change the tag cause this isnt angular 1.x

Comment: you have to make use of pipes , Angular pipes for displaying nested data in a json, can you post the json data . for reference    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705424/deep-nested-json-to-array-in-array-json-rendering-of-angular-2-ngfor

Comment: Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/96JrD09Xn9whEhup2Atr?p=preview Do you have a data structure like this?

Comment: @echonax I think not. its an array weeks that consists of four days arrays right?

Comment: @sadboy yep. What does your array looks like, can you provide it in your question?

Comment: @echonax does that provide you any information?
http://oi65.tinypic.com/sp905u.jpg

It's a console log from each weeks[i]

Comment: @sadboy ok what is the day object like? Is it just a date object?

Comment: @echonax Yeh, weeks[x][y] is a date object

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 2D Array, how are you expecting to access the days in the week using `week.days`?

Doing `let week of weeks` in the first `*ngFor` means that the `week` variable is now equal to a 1D array of days (a.k.a. `weeks[i]`).

Therefore your nested loop should simply be `let day of week` instead of `let day of week.days`.

Answer (score 0):

> // First you have to loop through each 'week' Object:

```
<tr *ngFor="let week of weeks">
```

> // Then you have to loop through each 'day' Object of the child Array
>   of Objects that are containing your days

```
<td *ngFor="let day of week.days"> {{ day.name }}</td>
```

> // {{ day.name }} represents your 'name' Object property if exists (
>   it may be used under different convention )