# nested array rendering using ngFor angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, ngfor

I have a table where tr is repeated using `*ngFor` a collection, the collection which have a child members which should be binded as related table.

*Note This is similar to nested array but only difference the html is not inside the nested array.* I have referenced [ngFor deep nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705424/deep-nested-json-to-array-in-array-json-rendering-of-angular-2-ngfor) already

> typescript class

```
export class CreateBooking{
 id: number;
 bookings: BookingItem[]; // This should repeat as parent rows,
} 

export class BookingItem {
 id: number;
 bookingNumber: number;
 relatedVehicles: BookingItem[]; //This should be repeated as child rows
}
```

**Html**

```
<table>

<tr *ngFor="let booking of createBooking.bookings;let bookingIndex = index;">
  <td>
  <input type="text" 
         [ngModel]="booking.serialType" name="serialType--{{bookingIndex}}" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr> *ngFor="let v of booking[parent].relatedVehicles;
      let i = index;
      let parent = booking[something];"

 <td>
  <input [(ngModel)]="v.bookingNumber"
        (ngModelChange)="serialNumberChangedIndex(parentIndex,$event,i)" 
        name="bookingNumber--{{i}}"/>
 </td>

</tr>

</table>
```

- Question 1 - How would i get the index of parent row on the child row
- Question 2 - As a alternative i tried a inside  which contains another table which have child items, But even with `td colspan="allcolumns"` i couldn't achieve expected output.

**Challenges**
 - if i design the like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let booking of createBooking.bookings;let bookingIndex = index;">
  <td>
  <input type="text" 
         [ngModel]="booking.serialType" name="serialType--{{bookingIndex}}" />
  </td> 

  <td>
     <table>
     <tbody>
     <tr> *ngFor="let v of booking.RelatedVehicles;let i = index;"
      <td>
     <input [(ngModel)]="v.bookingNumber"
        (ngModelChange)="serialNumberChangedIndex(bookingIndex ,$event,i)" 
        name="bookingNumber--{{i}}"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>

 </tr>
```

This way i could generate the Nested array but the child collection will start at the 2nd column, I need the child element as full row.

[Working sample code stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yca1rj)

Please help me with some

**expected output**

[image: Desired output file]

Comment: Can we see how `createBooking` is defined? Is `createBooking.bookings` a single instance of `bookings`? As for `serialType`, I assume that it is a string member of `bookings`.

Comment: Updated, @ConnorsFan.

Answer (score 0):

From your code above, I do not see any relation in the second  tag to the first one, where as your data structure I see the need for a nested tag. I think you should use a  tag for the outer loop and a  tag for the inner loop.

Comment: can you provide a sample code how to get a desired output