# Show Jason Data in Tree like structure in angular

Tags: json, angular

i have a `JSON` which is containing dynamic. So how to show `JSON` data into GUI tree structure i.e. expand and collapse in html page in angular ?

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "examName": "tt2",
    "examStatus": "INCOMPLETE",
    "examConfigStatus": {
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "generalConfigStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "instructConfigStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "timeConfigStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "marksConfigStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "questionPaperStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "numQuestionsExam": 12,
        "questionPapers": [
            {
                "status": "COMPLETED",
                "launguage": "ENGLISH",
                "minNumSetsPerLanguage": 2,
                "questionSets": [
                    {
                        "status": "COMPLETED",
                        "setName": "SET_A",
                        "numQuestions": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "status": "COMPLETED",
                        "setName": "SET_B",
                        "numQuestions": 12
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "shiftStatusList": [
        {
            "shiftId": 9,
            "shiftName": "Shift1",
            "shiftDate": "2019-12-10",
            "shiftStartTime": "09:00",
            "shiftEndTime": "12:00",
            "status": "INCOMPLETE",
            "centreStatusList": [
                {
                    "caId": 13,
                    "centreName": "ORNATE",
                    "status": "INCOMPLETE",
                    "numAvailableTerminals": 17,
                    "numAllocatedTerminals": 0,
                    "numFreeTerminals": 17,
                    "numApplicants": 0,
                    "moderators": [],
                    "hallStatusList": [
                        {
                            "hallName": "ORNATE",
                            "status": "COMPLETED",
                            "numAvailableTerminals": 17,
                            "numAllocatedTerminals": 0,
                            "supervisors": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "shiftId": 10,
            "shiftName": "shift2",
            "shiftDate": "2019-12-10",
            "shiftStartTime": "13:00",
            "shiftEndTime": "16:00",
            "status": "INCOMPLETE",
            "centreStatusList": [
                {
                    "caId": 12,
                    "centreName": "ORNATE",
                    "status": "INCOMPLETE",
                    "numAvailableTerminals": 17,
                    "numAllocatedTerminals": 0,
                    "numFreeTerminals": 17,
                    "numApplicants": 0,
                    "moderators": [],
                    "hallStatusList": [
                        {
                            "hallName": "ORNATE",
                            "status": "COMPLETED",
                            "numAvailableTerminals": 17,
                            "numAllocatedTerminals": 0,
                            "supervisors": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can use recursive ngFor..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733186/angular2-ul-li-json-tree-recursive-in-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the components available in angular like ngx-treeview,Kendo UI for Angular.
Below are the links- 
[For Kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/)

[For ngx-tree view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview)

Comment: Please do not answer questions like this where the OP has made zero effort. It just makes them go on to ask [even more low-effort questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383035/protect-existing-pdf-file-in-folder-with-password-and-email-as-attachment-in-asp) and degrades the quality of the site as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Save this json to a variable

```
let data = YOUR_JSON ;
```

Use it in html as follows:

Sample tag:

```
<p> examName: {{data.examName}} </p>
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions like this where the OP has made zero effort. It just makes them go on to ask [even more low-effort questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383035/protect-existing-pdf-file-in-folder-with-password-and-email-as-attachment-in-asp) and degrades the quality of the site as a whole.