# Angular - display any json data on the view component view in a loop without knowing the structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have some json data that I need to display on my app.component.html

Here is some sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "d1",
    "days": [
      "monday",
      "wednesday",
    ],
    "options": {
      "name": "o1",
      "extras": [],
      "temp": [
        "12",
        "25",
        "12"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "d2",
    "days": [
      "tuesday",
      "wednesday",
    ],
    "options": {
      "name": "o2a",
      "extras": [
        {
          name: 'extra 1'
        }
      ],
      "temp": [
        "22",
        "25",
        "12"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

At the moment I have it this way:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data">
  <li>{{dat.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

..etc

But the key names and values are not fixed so they can change and be more or less.

My question is, how can I do this where it can read any json data?

Comment: Can you show what you expect the generated html to become with the sample data? In the case of `name`, it's easy: you just want it inside the `<li>`, but in the case of `days` and `options`, it's not very clear

Comment: @ShamPooSham, What I understood is, the user's JSON key names are not final but he/she wants to ensure the data gets displayed without breaking even if the key names gets changed in future. So, I was suggesting that it may not be possible.

Comment: so you're basically asking how do I keep displaying a chicken if tomorrow they call it a cow. I'm not sure its possible unless you're willing to show the whole farm using `<pre> data | json</pre>`

Comment: you can try `recursive template` there are many examples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733186/angular2-ul-li-json-tree-recursive-in-ngfor 
 or  https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@jaysermendez/angular-tricks-recursively-rendering-a-tree-structure it depends how enhanced view you are need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a nicer Angular or JS JSON Tree viewer, but this can get you started.  You need to recursively iterate through your objects.

I'm using recursive template outlets here, you may be able to do components (and if you need to add other functionality its probably worth looking into that).

Here's a demo on stack blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qadvlr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Example component, it just has your data as an array, and a helper method to try and determine the type of value we got passed in, since its type will determine how we need to display it.

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  data1 = [
    {
      "name": "d1",
      "days": [
        "monday",
        "wednesday",
      ],
      "options": {
        "name": "o1",
        "extras": [],
        "temp": [
          "12",
          "25",
          "12"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "d2",
      "days": [
        "tuesday",
        "wednesday",
      ],
      "options": {
        "name": "o2a",
        "extras": [
          {
            name: 'extra 1'
          }
        ],
        "temp": [
          "22",
          "25",
          "12"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]

  getType(val: any) {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {// aray's will be type of "object" so need specail cases, and possibly others but this is a good start
      return 'array';
    } else if (typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String) {
      return 'string';
    } else if (typeof val === 'boolean') {
      return 'boolean';
    } else if (typeof val === "object") {
      return 'object'
    }
  }

}
```

Kinda messy, recursive templates that don't care about property names.  Instead we use Angular's `keyvalue` pipe to get the keys/values of an object.

```html
<ul *ngFor="let someObj of data1;">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="objectTemplate; context: {obj: someObj}"></ng-container>
</ul>


<ng-template #recursiveTemplate let-key="key" let-valueType="valueType" let-value="value">
  {{key}}

  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="valueType">

      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'array'">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="arrayTemplate; context: { value: value}"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'object'">
        <ul>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="objectTemplate; context: {obj: value}"></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- anything we might have missed or don't needs anything special for, just show it as JSON -->
      <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
         {{key ? "- " : ""}}{{value | json}}
      </ng-container>

  </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #arrayTemplate let-value="value">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let child of value;">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTemplate; context:{ key:null, valueType: getType(child), value: child }"></ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #objectTemplate let-obj="obj">
  <li *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue;">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTemplate; context:{ key:item.key, valueType: getType(item.value), value: item.value }"></ng-container>
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing `<li>{{dat.name}}</li>` and expecting everything to work if the key `name` gets changed, then its not possible.

However, If you just want to display the whole JSON in your UI, you can use `json` pipe like ::

`<li>{{dat | json}}</li>`

If you want the JSON gets displayed in pretty printed format, please change to ::

```
<div *ngFor="let dat of data">
    <pre>{{dat | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it just put the whole data between <li></li> ... I need to get some formatting for example if "extras": [], was not empty then I would need to add <ul> before the <li>

Comment: This I guess will not be possible... If you are worried about the formatting.. you can try out like ::

<div *ngFor="let dat of data">
 <pre>{{dat | json}}</pre>
</div>

Comment: Basically I want to have a treeview that displays the json data

Comment: I understood but I am just trying to suggest is everything is possible but this may not be possible if you want your code to be working even if the key names gets changed.  You'll need to either display the entire JSON or you'll need to finalize JSON and decorate the UI

Answer (score 1):

Just do this.

```
<pre>
{{ data | json }}
</pre>
```