# Invalid argument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular

So i get this when i try to get my data from firebase

```
Invalid argument '{"-KCO4lKzEJPRq0QgkfHO":{"description":"teste","id":1457488598401,"resourceUrl":"tete","title":"test2"}}' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [listItems | async  in ArcListComponent@2:10]
```

ArcListComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "angular2/core";
import { FirebaseService } from "../shared/firebase.service";
import { ArcItem } from "./arc-item.model";


@Component({
    selector: "arc-list",
    template: `
    <ul class="arc-list">
      <li *ngFor="#item of listItems | async " class="arc-item">
        <h3>{{ item.name}}</h3><a [href]="item.resourceUrl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span>Go</span></a>
        <hr>
        <blockquote>{{ item.description }}</blockquote>
        <hr>

      </li>
    </ul>
    `

})

export class ArcListComponent implements OnInit {
  listItems: string;

  constructor(private _firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this._firebaseService.getResources().subscribe(
      resource => this.listItems = JSON.stringify(resource),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

firebase_service

```
import { Injectable } from "angular2/core";
import { Http } from "angular2/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  setResource(id: number, title: string, description: string, resourceUrl: string) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({ id: id, title: title, description: description, resourceUrl: resourceUrl});

    return this._http
                     .post("https://######.firebaseio.com/resource.json", body)
                     .map(response => response.json());
  }

  getResources() {
    return this._http
                     .get("https://######.firebaseio.com/resource.json")
                     .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

I know i am trying to show my data the wrong way but i do not know how to fix this. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

The `async` pipe expects an observable or a promise. `http.get` and `map` operator return observable, so you can set the returned object into the `listItems` property of your component. You don't need to subscribe in this case:

```
this.listItems = this._firebaseService.getResources();
```

Moreover the object, this element will "receive" must be an array to be able to use it within an `ngFor`. You service returns an object and not an array from Firebase. If you want to iterate over the keys of the object, you need to implement a custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "arc-list",
  template: `
  <ul class="arc-list">
    <li *ngFor="#item of listItems | async | keys" class="arc-item">
      <h3>{{ item.value.name}}</h3><a [href]="item.value.resourceUrl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span>Go</span></a>
      <hr>
      <blockquote>{{ item.value.description }}</blockquote>
      <hr>

    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
  pipes: [ KeysPipe ]
})
```

See this question for more details:

- [How to display json object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647365/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor/35647396)

Comment: Does this also then mean I don't need to call unsubscribe as it's handled by the framework?

Comment: The Async pipe automatically handles subscription and unsubscription for you.

Answer (score 4):

`async` pipe works with observables and/or promises. It does subscription for you, so you just have to pass an observable without subscribing to it in your code:

```
  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.listItems = this._firebaseService.getResources()
  }
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your comments, now i get this `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' in [listItems | async in ArcListComponent@2:10]` Note that i had to change my listItems type to Observable<any> also.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou your Observable/Promise must return an array, NgFor doesn't iterate over objects.

Comment: @EricMartinez is there an example of you what you mean? i am new to this kind of stuff. I mean i understand what you say just do not know how to do it