# InvalidPipeArgument using ng-select model binding in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to bind my typescript model to data from the backend to display in an ng-select dropdown.
My HTML for ng-select looks like the following:

```
<ng-select [items]="employeeAccounts | async" (change)="accountSelected($event)" [loading]="isLoadingAccounts" placeholder="Please Select"></ng-select>
```

My Typescript for gathering the data to be displayed in the dropdown looks like the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployeeAccounts(1);
  }

getEmployeeAccounts(employeeId) {
    this.isLoadingAccounts = true;
      this._apiService.GetEmployeeAccounts(
        (data) => {//success
          this.employeeAccounts = data;
          this.isLoadingAccounts = false;
        },
        (data) => {//error
          alert('Something went wrong!');
          this.isLoadingAccounts = false;
        },
        employeeId);
  }
```

However when I run the application I get the following error:

> ConfigurationComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument:
>   '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>           at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4283)
>           at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:5732)
>           at AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:5714)
>           at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:5688)
>           at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ConfigurationComponent.html:6)
>           at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)

I believe it is because of the async keyword defined in ng-select, however without it the dropdown doesn't show any items, but also doesnt throw any errors.

My question is about ng-select (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) InvalidPipeArgument error. It is a unique question, not a duplicate.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what is in your employeeAccounts ? array or object ?. check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881721/invalid-argument-for-pipe-asyncpipe)

Comment: @akhilaravind employeeAccounts is an array of EmployeeAccount objects.

Comment: @DanielBeckmann no this is not a duplicate - this question is about ng-select, that post is not about ng-select.

Comment: It is irrelevant whether it is used with ng-select or a ngFor. As the answer in the referenced links says: "The async pipe expects an observable or a promise." You assign the result of your service request to an array/object (employeeAccounts) - this is not the way the AsyncPipe is working.