# error display in *ngfor json array object

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

when fetching json array object from rest api and trying to display in ngfor failed with the reason

## error

EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in [indexes in HomeComponent@5:37]

Code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HomeService} from './home.services';
import {Index} from './index';

@Component({
    selector: 'home-app',
    providers: [HomeService],

    template: `
        <section class="left_side">
            <article>
                <div class="div_home">
                    <div class="div_homeIndxPartition">
                        <div class="div_IndxPartition" *ngFor="#indObj of indexes">
                            <table width="500px" class="idx_cons_table_det">
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center" color="#A9F5F2"><h3>{{indObj.name}} ({{indObj.tracker}})</h3></th>
                                    <th align="center">Value</th>
                                    <th align="center">Change</th>
                                    <th align="center">%</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="1"></td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.value}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.change}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.percent}}%</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br/>
                            <table width="500px" class="idx_cons_table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center">High</th>
                                    <th align="center">Low</th>
                                    <th align="center">Open</th>
                                    <th align="center">Close</th>
                                    <th align="center">52 Week High</th>
                                    <th align="center">52 Week Low</th>                             
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.high}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.low}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.open}}%</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.close}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.yearHigh}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{indObj.yearLow}}%</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                        
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    `

})
export class HomeComponent {
    public indexes:Array<Index>=[];
    public error;

constructor(private _service: HomeService){
    this.indexes = _service.getIndexes().subscribe(
            data => this.indexes =  JSON.parse(data),
            error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
            ()=> console.log("finished")
         );
    console.log(this.indexes);
}
}
```

## JSON Data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "FTSE 100",
    "ticker": "UKX",
    "value": 69875.23,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 69875.23,
    "low": 69700.89,
    "yearHigh": 699999.23,
    "yearLow": 680005.23,
    "open": 69600.54,
    "close": 699000.97,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "FTSE 250",
    "ticker": "MCX",
    "value": 465820.85,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 465880.12,
    "low": 465810.74,
    "yearHigh": 478990.34,
    "yearLow": 465320.23,
    "open": 69600.54,
    "close": 699000.97,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "FTSE All-Share",
    "ticker": "ASX",
    "value": 236549.23,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 236949.23,
    "low": 236149,
    "yearHigh": 246949.21,
    "yearLow": 235549.29,
    "open": 236519.23,
    "close": 236649.23,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Euro Stoxx 50",
    "ticker": "STOXX50E",
    "value": 123469.87,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 123499.87,
    "low": 123439.87,
    "yearHigh": 123499.87,
    "yearLow": 123169.87,
    "open": 123465.87,
    "close": 123459.87,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "S&P 500 ",
    "ticker": "S500",
    "value": 358976.36,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 358986.36,
    "low": 358946.36,
    "yearHigh": 359976.36,
    "yearLow": 357976.36,
    "open": 358970.36,
    "close": 358996.36,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Dow Jones I.A.",
    "ticker": "INDU",
    "value": 456789.36,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 456799.36,
    "low": 456779.36,
    "yearHigh": 456889.36,
    "yearLow": 456689.36,
    "open": 456729.36,
    "close": 456779.36,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "GOLD",
    "ticker": "",
    "value": 500,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 700,
    "low": 300,
    "yearHigh": 1500,
    "yearLow": 350,
    "open": 450,
    "close": 470,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Brent Crude",
    "ticker": "",
    "value": 112,
    "change": 100,
    "percent": 2.3,
    "high": 115,
    "low": 107,
    "yearHigh": 200,
    "yearLow": 72,
    "open": 110,
    "close": 115,
    "constituents": null,
    "runDate": "21/04/2015"
  }
]
```

Comment: Use `data.json()` instead parsing it manually.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the value you set in the `indexes` property isn't an array but an object.

I would see several reasons for this:

- You receive the response instead of the payload from the `getIndexes` method. In this case, you could use the `map` operator in this method:

  ```
  getIndexes() {
    return this.http.get(...).map(res => res.json());
  }
  ```
- The received payload doesn't correspond to an array but some of its properties. In this case, you need to set this property into the `indexes` property.

If you want to iterate over the properties of an object, you need to implement a custom filter like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keyValues'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
<div class="div_IndxPartition" *ngFor="#indObj of indexes | keyValues">
  (...)
</div>
```

See this question:

- [How to display json object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647365/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor/35647396#35647396)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting json array and i thought it will be converted back to the domain object by reflection ? Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: Using "response.json()" parses the text response payload as json. The corresponding object will be an object...

Comment: What is "data"? Howdo you get it?

Comment: this.indexes = _service.getIndexes().subscribe(
            data => this.indexes =  JSON.parse(data),
            error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
            ()=> console.log("finished")
         );

data is the json data from server which i have posted in the question last session.

Comment: what i'm confused is, we cant display the domain object as an array in the *NG and json to domain object will not be done by reflection if u set the property type you are assiging.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

**In html:**

```
<div  *ngFor="let subsciption of subscriptions;">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5 class="widget-title">{{subsciption.name}}</h5>
                    </div>
</div>
```

**in .ts file:**

```
    export class SubscriptionComponent implements OnInit {
        private subscriptions: any =[]; 
        // private subscriptions: any ={};    // here dont use {}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

        getAllSubscriptions(queryString) {
            this._http.get(`${environment.base_url}/subscriptions` + queryString)
                .subscribe((response: Response) => {
                    this.subscriptions = response.json();
                },

                (error: Response) => {
                    console.log("Login error");
                });
        }
        this.getAllSubscriptions(query);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and my solution was without Pipes. I did not use variable in the template that returns Observer, create intermediate variable and assign result to it. For example, we will save stream to `this.sub` but result will save to `this.indexes` on success callback and will use this variable in the html template.

```
@Component({
  template: `
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let index of indexs">
    {{ index }}
  </li>
</ul>
`
})
export class HomeComponent {
  privat sub;
  public indexes:Array<Index>=[];
  public error;

  constructor(private _service: HomeService) {
    this.sub = this._service.getIndexes().subscribe(
        data => this.indexes =  JSON.parse(data),
        error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
        () => console.log("finished")
     );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use pipes when working with Observables.
This error is very generic and the best way is to throw in a console.log() and see where you are going wrong as it could be numerous things.

My problem was my Array was inside the Object, and I was trying to loop over the Object. Other problems could include the mapping or the ngFor. My console output would look something like this:

```
this.indexes = _service.getIndexes()
         .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.indexes = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(indexes);
            },
            error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
                ()=> console.log("finished")
         );
    console.log(this.indexes);
```

So the fix I needed was something like this:

```
this.indexes = _service.getIndexes()
             .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.myNewObject = JSON.parse(data);
                    this.indexes = this.myNewObject.indexes;
                },
                error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
                    ()=> console.log("finished")
             );
        console.log(this.indexes);
```

This was because the array was nested inside the Object, so I just created a new object and accessed the array by getting its property.

Answer (score 0):

i see your answer, and the easy way to solve is just set the type of the object in the *ngFor to array like this:

```
public indexes:Array<TYPE_OF_YOUR_DATA>=[];
```