# Ionic 2/Angular 2 display array

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic2

I have to do a mobile application for school and I choosed to use Ionic 2 for this.

I need to display the daily timetable/schedule. For this, I'm using our intranet's API which returns a json, for exemple :

```
{
    "1": [],
    "4": {
        "matiere": "M4201",
        "prof": "LANDRÉ Jérôme",
        "salle": "H201",
        "evaluation": "N",
        "texte": null,
        "commentaire": null,
        "type": "td",
        "fin": 7
    },
    "7": {
        "matiere": "M4204",
        "prof": "GOMMERY Patrice",
        "salle": "H205",
        "evaluation": "N",
        "texte": null,
        "commentaire": null,
        "type": "tp",
        "fin": 10
    },
    "13": {
        "matiere": "",
        "prof": "",
        "salle": "****",
        "evaluation": "N",
        "texte": "PROJETS",
        "commentaire": null,
        "type": "CM",
        "fin": 19
    },
    "16": [],
    "19": [],
    "22": []
}
```

I successfully retrieve this in my application, but I dont find how to display of list of this.

Here is my /home/home.ts script :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Home } from '../../models/home';
import { HomeCours } from '../../providers/home-cours';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  cours: Home[]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private HomeCours: HomeCours) {
    HomeCours.load().subscribe(cours => {
      console.log(cours)
    })
  }

}
```

My /models/home.ts :

```
/**
 * Created by corentin on 17/03/2017.
 */
//récupère la liste des cours sur http://intranet.iut-troyes.univ-reims.fr/api/edtjour/< id de la personne qui consulte  >

export interface Home {
  matiere: string;
  prof: string;
  salle: string;
  evaluation: string;
  texte: string;
  commentaire: string;
  type: string;
  fin: number;
}
```

My /providers/home-cours.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Home } from '../models/home';

/*
  Generated class for the HomeCours provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class HomeCours {
  coursApiUrl = 'https://api.corentincloss.fr/intranet/edt.php?id=';
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello HomeCours Provider');
  }

  load(): Observable<Home[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.coursApiUrl}closs006`).map(res => <Home[]>res.json());
  }

}
```

and finally my home.html :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Mes cours</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Emploi du temps du jour.</h2>
  <hr />
  <ion-list>
    <div ion-item *ngFor="let cour of cours">
      <h2>{{ cour.matiere }}</h2>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I'm sure this is coming from the id ("1", "4", "7"...) but I don't find any way to search the datas in those arrays.

If you could help me please it would be great :D

Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of `console.log(cours)`, initialize the field of your component: `this.cours = cours`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found, I had to declare a new array named "cours".

Here is my cours.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CoursService } from '../../providers/cours-service';

/*
  Generated class for the Cours page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cours',
  templateUrl: 'cours.html',
  providers: [CoursService]
})
export class CoursPage {
  public cours: any;
  public heures: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public coursService: CoursService) {
    this.loadCours();
    console.log(coursService);
  }

  loadCours(){
    this.coursService.load()

      .then(data => {
        let cours = new Array();
        for (let key in data) {
          cours.push(data[key]);
        }
        this.cours = cours;
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CoursPage');
  }

}
```

And now it's perfectly working ! Thank you for your answers :)

[image: Working array]

Answer (score 2):

After you've obtained the data, you should assign it to a property in your class:

```
export class HomePage {
  cours: Home[]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private HomeCours: HomeCours) {
    HomeCours.load().subscribe(cours => this.cours = cours);
  }

}
```

Comment: I did this, now I have an error, but I think this topic could help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839223/error-display-in-ngfor-json-array-object

Answer (score 0):

You can't `*ngFor` object. You should make an array from object.

```
export class HomePage {
  cours: Home[] = []

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private HomeCours: HomeCours) {
    HomeCours.load().subscribe((data: any) => for (let key in data) this.cours.push({key: key, value: cours[key]}););
  }    
}
```