# iteration a json object on Ngfor in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, observable, ngfor

I'm having trouble iteration a json object in the Ngfor, there is my template :

template:

```
<h1>Hey</h1>
  <div>{{ people| json}}</div>
  <h1>***************************</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#person of people">
        {{
          person.label
        }}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

people is the json object that I'm trying to iterate, I'm having rhe result of (people | json) and not getting the list, here is a screenshot:

[image]

and to finish, here is a part of json file :

```
{
"actionList": {
"count": 35,
"list": [
    {
    "Action": {
        "label": "A1",
        "HTTPMethod": "POST",
        "actionType": "indexation",
        "status": "active",
        "description": "Ajout d'une transcription dans le lac de données",
        "resourcePattern": "transcriptions/",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "Parameter": {
                    "label": "",
                    "description": "Flux JSON à indexer",
                    "identifier": "2",
                    "parameterType": "body",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "requestType": "Action",
                    "processParameter": {
                        "label": "",
                        "description": "Flux JSON à indexer",
                        "identifier": "4",
                        "parameterType": "body",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "requestType": "Process"
                    }
                }
            },
```

please feel free to help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `people` object isn't an array so you can iterate over it out of the box.

There is two options:

- You want to iterate over a sub property. For example:

  ```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#person of people?.actionList?.list">
      {{
        person.label
      }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- You want to iterate over the keys of your object. In this case, you need to implement a custom pipe:

  ```
  @Pipe({name: 'keys'})
  export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
      if (!value) {
        return value;
      } 

      let keys = [];
      for (let key in value) {
        keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
      } 
      return keys;
    } 
  }
  ```

  and use it this way:

  ```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#person of people | keys">
      {{
        person.value.xx
      }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

  See this answer for more details:

  - [How to display json object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647365/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor/35647396#35647396)

Comment: thank you a lot thierry, i've add the pipe as you mentioned, in my template, i've call it like this and still don't get anything :                                                    <li *ngFor="#person of people | keys ">
            {{
              msg.value.Action.label
            }}
        </li>                         // for example getting all the labels under each action node

Comment: when i'm trying it like this : <li *ngFor="#obj of lists  ">
            {{
               obj.value.list[0].Action.label
            }}
        </li>     i'm getting the label : A120, and not the first label A1, and i'm getting just a one element not a list, is it normal ??

Comment: i've tried to add the index into it like this, it did not work :   <li *ngFor="#obj of lists | keys, #i=index ">
            {{
               obj.value.list[i].Action.label
            }}
        </li>  // how can i pass the index value inside the list ??