# How to repeat a json object in angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

like in angular 1 we can repeat json object in following way :

```
ng-repeat="state(k,v) in states"
```

then using `{{k}}` or `{{v}}`

But how to do it for angular 2 ?

```
*ngFor="let state of states"
```

Comment: How does your JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't seen a simpler method to iterate and get the keys using '*NgFor' than the one here: [iteration a json object on Ngfor in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431578/iteration-a-json-object-on-ngfor-in-angular-2)

It's basically creating a custom pipe to set the keys as properties you can access in the loop.

Hope it helps.