# How to get data as Ionic's list from Firebase's JSON

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I would like to display a list of items, retrieved from Firebase realtime database, on my page. My problem is that I need to parse JSON that I receive from Firebase and put it into an object so that I can call it from page.

```
export class Item { name: string, price: number }
```

Page code:

```
export class ItemsPage {

private itemsList; 
private userId;
private userFirebaseToken;

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          private userService: UserService) {} 



   this.userService.getItemsList(this.userId, this.userFirebaseToken)
                .subscribe(
                  items => this.itemsList = items,
                  error => console.log(error),
                  () => console.log('OK')
                );

}
```

Service code:

```
getItemsList(userId: string, userToken: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.userServiceUrl + userId + '/items.json?auth='+ userToken)
                    .map((response: Response) => response);
```

EDIT: Change the object into Array that can be called in ngFor directives. Now I have been getting [object Object]

Comment: you can print the object in console with `console.log(JSON.stringify(your_object))`

Comment: @suraj , yes, I have the JSON object, but since it is from Firebase, it is like `{'someRandomID':{'name':'abc','price':'233'},'someRandomID2':{'name':'zxc','price':'987'}}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431578/iteration-a-json-object-on-ngfor-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your `map function`.It will send the parsed json to your `subscribe`

Try:

```
 .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: When I do this, it will go to error, and console log error message as null

Comment: That means you are getting null response. you need to check wether your firebase api is working correctly

Comment: I actually did. A console log at the service returns a full JSON when I use JSON.stringify.

Comment: @AfeezAziz : Code Suraj posted is correct. May be your URL `this.userServiceUrl + userId + '/items.json?auth='+ userToken` is incorrect or returning nothing. If not, there is something not correctly happening in the flow.

Comment: @sagarKulkarni and, yes I have been receiving an object. I have edited my question to reflect that I want to change this JSON to array to be used by the page.