# Loop through array of strings - angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-template

Yet very basic thing, but I am unable to figure out how to display array of strings in html template in angular2.

.html

```
<ul>
       <li *ngFor="#number of numberOptions">
          {{number}}
       </li>
</ul>
```

.ts

`this.numberOptions= ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"];`

The above trick is not working for me, text editor shows error for `#number` in `ngFor`. Is this deprecated in new versions? or am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to declare the variable `number` with `let`.

```
   <li *ngFor="let number of numberOptions">
      {{number}}
   </li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering why `#number` isn't working.

Comment: Because you have to declare the variable with `let`. Is like traditional `for` in javascript: `for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ){}`. This is the same thing, but instead of `var` you have to use `let` since this is TypeScript. You need to declare the variable within the scope block of the for, not use a declared variable outside it.

Comment: I am very well aware of `let` in typescript, but my question is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431578/iteration-a-json-object-on-ngfor-in-angular-2 If you see the post they have declared variable using using `#`

Comment: @AmitChigadani the `#` syntax was used in beta versions of Angular.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a ton @AJT_82

Answer (score 5):

use let instead of #

```
<ul>
       <li *ngFor="let number of numberOptions">
          {{number}}
       </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
       <li *ngFor="let number of numberOptions">
          {{number}}
       </li>
</ul>
```