# Models in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular4-forms

I have this model

```
export class model{
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
  home: Home[];
}

export class Home{
  street: string;
  country: string;
  CP: string;
}
```

the question is how to use the values of model Home in father model and use the values in a form to insert new register for example:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" ([ngModel])="model.id">
 <input type="text" ([ngModel])="model.Name">
 <input type="text" ([ngModel])="model.Home.CP"><!--How to implements the values of home to insert a value in the BD-->
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: What is a father module?

Comment: Also casing matters and if you are going to access an item in an array you need to use the array indexer or loop through it and access it multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851357/loop-through-array-of-strings-angular2

Answer (score 0):

@Juan Perez

To use `Home[]` array in `model` class, you need to instantiate the array in the `model` class constructor. Then when binding data to the `home` property of the `model` class, you have to use an index in the `home` array. Possible code would look like below

```
<input type="text" ([ngModel])="model.home[index].CP">
```

In the `model` class the constructor should look like below

```
export class model{
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
  home: Home[];

  model() {
    home = new Array(3).fill(new Home());
  }
}

export class Home{
  street: string;
  country: string;
  CP: string;

  Home() {
    street = "";
    country = "";
    CP = "";
  }
}
```