# How to iterate json object using ngFor in Angular 4

Tags: arrays, json, angular

**Problem:**

I have below code:

```
<div>
   {{ data | json }}
</div>
```

which produces results in following `json` format

```
[  
 {  
  "display_title":"Megan Leavey",
  "mpaa_rating":"PG-13",
  "critics_pick":1,
  "byline":"NEIL GENZLINGER",
  "headline":"Review: In ‘Megan Leavey,’ a Marine, Her Dog and a Bond Forged in War",
  "summary_short":"Based on a true story, this film, starring Kate Mara, is both harrowing and heartstring-tugging.",
  "publication_date":"2017-06-08",
  "opening_date":"2017-06-09",
  "date_updated":"2017-06-09 02:44:28",
  "link":{  
     "type":"article",
     "url":"http://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/08/movies/megan-leavey-review-kate-mara.html",
     "suggested_link_text":"Read the New York Times Review of Megan Leavey"
  },
  "multimedia":{  
     "type":"mediumThreeByTwo210",
     "src":"https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/06/09/arts/09MEGAN/09MEGAN-mediumThreeByTwo210.jpg",
     "width":210,
     "height":140
  }
},
{  
  "display_title":"The Hero",
  "mpaa_rating":"R",
  "critics_pick":1,
  "byline":"JEANNETTE CATSOULIS",
  "headline":"Review: For an Aging Actor, Another Chance to Be ‘The Hero’",
  "summary_short":"Brett Haley’s low-key feature, about an older actor seeking redemption after being reduced to a cliché, belongs to its star, Sam Elliott.",
  "publication_date":"2017-06-08",
  "opening_date":"2017-06-09",
  "date_updated":"2017-06-09 02:44:28",
  "link":{  
     "type":"article",
     "url":"http://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/08/movies/the-hero-review-sam-elliott.html",
     "suggested_link_text":"Read the New York Times Review of The Hero"
  },
  "multimedia":{  
     "type":"mediumThreeByTwo210",
     "src":"https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/06/09/arts/09HERO/09HERO-mediumThreeByTwo210.jpg",
     "width":210,
     "height":140
  }
 }
]
```

and my `pipe` codes

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
 export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
  if (!value) {
     return value;
  } 

let keys = [];
 for (let key in value) {
   keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
   } 
   return keys;
 } 
}
```

Using suggestion from [iteration a json object on Ngfor in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431578/iteration-a-json-object-on-ngfor-in-angular-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) ,

I am trying to achieve movie title like this:

```
<ul class="suggestions" >
    <li class="suggestion1" *ngFor="#movie of data | keys">

        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="username">{{ movie.display_title }} </a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

but it throws `error` like

> zone.js:642 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#movie of data | keys] in ng:///AppModule/RoughWorkComponent.html

I am using `Angular 4.1.3`

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 4.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*ngFor="#movie of data | keys">
```

needs to be

```
*ngFor="let movie of data | keys">
```

you are using the old syntax

**Edit:** As [@AJT_82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294072/ajt-82) stated the object is an array not a JSON, so there's no need for the pipe:

`*ngFor="let movie of data"` is enough

Comment: @Hiranya can you remove `if (!value) {
     return value;
  }` line and try?

Comment: `data` is an array... ;)