# Angular 2 show/ hide dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Based on the response I get , I will be generating the divs dynamically . for instance if my response is

```
Array = {response: {  
                  " para1" : "para1name", 
                   " para2" : "para2name"
              }
}

<div *ngFor="let x of Array; > 
<button>x.para1</button>
<div > content for para1</div>
</div>
```

I have to store all the properties from json into an array and iterate through it to display the divs. In this case I should have 2 divs  But its not working . and also when I click on the button for para1 then div for para1 should be shown n when I click on para2 div I should hide div for para1 and should show div for para2 . how this can be accomplished.

Comment: The array has only one element object with two properties.

Comment: Can you help me to implement it

Comment: Can you post your expected array? Is it the same (object with two properties para1 and para2)?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to that solution where you want to iterate usings keys of your json object https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431657/2013245

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    if (!value) {
      return value;
    } 

    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    } 
    return keys;
  } 
}
```

the above code will push your keys and values in an array whereby you can iterate.

Then in your component.ts, you can do something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let x of Array;" >
 <div *ngFor="#temp of x | keys"> 
   <button>temp.para1</button>
   <div> content for para1</div>
 <div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.. Is there any post that would guide to show n hide the divs.. That's was the major task

Comment: did you try ngIf?

Comment: NgIf ?? How that could help

Comment: advancesharp.com/blog/1212/…. Can you please check that link and see if that could help with show and hide dynamically? Any question you may ask. I just tried it. it works

Answer (score -1):

```
show: boolean = false;

clicked() {

      console.log("clicked");
      this.show = !this.show;
```

}

your html code -

`input type="submit" value="Search" (click)="clicked()"`

```
<div *ngIf="show">
your div content to be displayed dynamically
</div>
```

Comment: Please take care of your formatting and try to make it a little more descriptive.

Comment: I'm new to this site, facing a little difficulties..!!

Comment: No worries, we all are newbies some time. Please consider to walk through the help and FAQ section: https://stackoverflow.com/help