# Display objects in the view Angular4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
   { player0: {select_by: "player_id", i: 107993, role: "main", team: "team1"}
    player1: {select_by: "player_id", i: 108322, role: "main", team: "team1"}
    player2: {select_by: "player_id", i: 107995, role: "main", team: "team1"}
    player3: {select_by: "player_id", i: 108033, role: "main", team: "team1"}
    player4: {select_by: "player_id", i: 108866, role: "main", team: "team1"}
}
```

How i can display this play of objects in the view ? ( Ionic3, Angular )
Display role of every player for example

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using the approach of this stackoverflow post: [How to display json object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647365/how-to-display-json-object-using-ngfor)

Another option would be creating a helper array where you put all players in.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-selector",
  templateUrl: "your.html",
  styleUrls: ["your.scss"]
})
export class Your-Class implements OnInit {
  public playerArr: Player[];
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerArr = [];
    // Iterate your object here named as players and push all players into array
    for(let player in players){
        this.playerArr.push(players[player]);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

After rebuilding your json as array you can easily use the `*ngFor` in your html to loop the array and retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular 6.1 or greater you can use `keyValue` pipe

Try something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of playersObject | keyvalue;>{{item.key}} : {{ item.value.role }}</div>
```

If you want a plain object to load you can use `json` pipe

```
<div>{{playerObject | json}}</div>
```

Hope it works - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, try:

```
<div *ngFor="let player of players; let i = index">
   {{ player["player" + i]["role"] }}
<div>
```

players refers to the object you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The more better approach will be using pipes. Refer to this implementation at stackblitz.

Pipe Implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xvt2ha
OutPut :https://ionic-xvt2ha.stackblitz.io