# How can I communicate between two child components in angular?

Tags: angular, components

I'm very new in angular 2. I have a problem to communicate between two components. When I have a layout with a parent and some child components, it's easy to set variables of the child components with the @Input annotation.

But now I have a layout of one parent component (which is mostly for the layout) and two child components:

[image: example Layout]

The child component 2 have a bunch of buttons, which creates only a simple message. Now I want to display this message in child component one.

How do I resolve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: You need to use a shared service. More info [Angular2 - How to share data/change between components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878160/angular2-how-to-share-data-change-between-components)

Comment: @user1078685 he can, he doesn't need to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild` and `@Output` to update the properties in the child component.

Alternatively you can use 
`@Input` in place of `@ViewChild`.

The approach suggested by seidme will also work just fine. It just depends on your use case.

Example using `@ViewChild` and `@Output`:
https://plnkr.co/edit/r4KjoxLCFqkGzE1OkaQc?p=preview

Example using `@Input` and `@Output`
https://plnkr.co/edit/01iRyNSvOnOG1T03xUME?p=preview

Comment: looks like the simplest way. thanks for the plunker sample for better understaing. Now it works well

Answer (score 34):

Beside the solutions using the `@Input`/`@Output` and a parent component as a 'bridge', a common way would also be introducing a shared service. The service needs to be provided in a parent component so the children can share single instance of the service ([How do I create a singleton service in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2)).

Basic example using the [BehaviorSubject as a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2):

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    messageSource: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

    constructor() { }
}
```

Child component 1:

```
export class ChildComponent1 {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    sendMessage(): void {
        this.sharedService.messageSource.next('Hello from child 1!');
    }
}
```

Child component 2:

```
export class ChildComponent2 {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sharedService.messageSource.subscribe((message) => {
            console.log('Message: ', message); // => Hello from child 1!
        });
    }
}
```

See also: [Angular2 - Interaction between components using a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958836/angular2-interaction-between-components-using-a-service/41960007#41960007)

Comment: Facing a small issue. The message alert is coming on page load as well on route changes.

Comment: @PankajGarg It's beacuse BehaviorSubject upon a subscription returns the last value it holds Change BehaviorSubject with Subject if you don't want the value to be emitted on subscribe.

Comment: That works perfectly now. thanks a lot!

Comment: One more prob coming up, the first click is not responding now..second click onwards it is working fine.

Answer (score 19):

A simple way is to set an output with @Output in your child component2 as an eventemitter and emit a event with the message passed as a data of it when a button is clicked. Then, listen to this event in your parent component and update a property that is set as an input of your child component1 when the event occurs.

The image below is an example that clearly show the mechanism

[image: Component-IO]

Comment: The visualization is great, but the code should also be added as text to the question, for it to be searchable and copy-past-able.

Comment: Now you have three closely coupled components. So so.

Comment: I can't upvote you enough. So beautifully explained. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the diagram that explains the data flow so clearly. Although a shared service may be the preferred answer depending on context. A stackblitz of it would be invaluable.

Answer (score 16):

You can use template variables to reference siblings:

```html
<child1 #child1></child1>
<child2 (someOutput)="child1.doSomething($event)"></child2>
```

Comment: That what I was looking for, but I cant fight this Error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "#child1". Can you help me please.

Comment: Then you have probably different code. Perhaps some `=` near `#child`?

Comment: OMG... Pug converting 'search-form(#search)' to '<search-form #search="#search">' )))

Comment: It only works in the form I demonstrate in my answer. Could you make it work now?

Comment: The problem is I can't access 'child1' template variable from inside child1 component to set doSomethig method.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to my answer. Please create a new question with the full information what you try to accomplish, what you tried, where you failed and the code that allows to reproduce (ideally a http://stackblitz.com example)

Comment: Nop. I'm trying to implement your adwise exactly. Here is what I'm trying to: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ew3ipn

Comment: The task is to invoke method of first component with value taken from another one.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grrkzw

Comment: Thank you, you cool! Can't understand why everybody stack on shared services if there is so nice approach. Even in angular docs no way to find it...

Comment: It works only for siblings. Most scenarios are for components further apart and a shared service is a more generic solution. It works everywhere. But I like this approach as well where it is applicable.