# Angular 4 pass data between 2 not related components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a questions about passing data in Angular.

First, I don't have a structure as `<parent><child [data]=parent.data></child></parent>`

My structure is

```
<container>
  <navbar>
    <summary></summary>
    <child-summary><child-summary>
  </navbar>
  <content></content>
</container>
```

So, in `<summary />` I have a select that do send value to `<child-summary />` and `<content />`.

OnSelect method is well fired with (change) inside `<summary />` component.

So, I tried with `@Input`, `@Output` and `@EventEmitter` directives, but I don't see how retrieve the event as @Input of the component, unless to go on parent/child pattern. All examples I've founded has a relation between component.

EDIT : Example with BehaviorSubject not working (all connected service to API works well, only observable is fired at start but not when select has value changed)

shared service = company.service.ts (used to retrieve company data)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class SrvCompany {

    private accountsNumber = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);
    currentAccountsNumber = this.accountsNumber.asObservable();

    changeMessage(accountsNumber: string[]) {
        this.accountsNumber.next(accountsNumber);
    }

    private _companyUrl = 'api/tiers/';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getSociete(): Promise<Response> {
        let url = this._companyUrl;
        return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
    }
}
```

invoice.component.ts (the "child")

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { SrvInvoice } from './invoice.service';
import { SrvCompany } from '../company/company.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'invoice',
    templateUrl: 'tsScripts/invoice/invoice.html',
    providers: [SrvInvoice, SrvCompany]
})

export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit  {

    invoice: any;

    constructor(private srvInvoice: SrvInvoice, private srvCompany: SrvCompany)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //this.getInvoice("F001");

        // Invoice data is linked to accounts number from company.
        this.srvCompany.currentAccountsNumber.subscribe(accountsNumber => {
            console.log(accountsNumber);
            if (accountsNumber.length > 0) {
                this.srvInvoice.getInvoice(accountsNumber).then(data => this.invoice = data.json());
            }
        });
    }

    //getInvoice(id: any) {
    //    this.srvInvoice.getInvoice(id).then(data => this.invoice = data.json());
    //}
}
```

company.component.ts (the trigerring "parent")

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { SrvCompany } from './company.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'company',
    templateUrl: 'tsScripts/company/company.html',
    providers: [SrvCompany]    
})

export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {

    societes: any[];    
    soc: Response[]; // debug purpose
    selectedSociete: any;

    ville: any;
    ref: any;
    cp: any;
    accountNumber: any[];

    constructor(private srvSociete: SrvCompany)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getSocietes();
    }

    getSocietes(): void {

        this.srvSociete.getSociete()
            .then(data => this.societes = data.json())
            .then(data => this.selectItem(this.societes[0].Id));
    }

    selectItem(value: any) {
        this.selectedSociete = this.societes.filter((item: any) => item.Id === value)[0];
        this.cp = this.selectedSociete.CodePostal;
        this.ville = this.selectedSociete.Ville;
        this.ref = this.selectedSociete.Id;
        this.accountNumber = this.selectedSociete.Accounts;
        console.log(this.accountNumber);
        this.srvSociete.changeMessage(this.accountNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html?

Comment: yes, I've read it but example is ever about relation parent/child or child/parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interaction between components using a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958836/angular2-interaction-between-components-using-a-service)

Comment: Hmm no, my question is now specific.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is a case where you want to use a shared service, as your components are structured as siblings and grandchildren. Here's an example from a video I created a video about [sharing data between components](https://youtu.be/I317BhehZKM) that solves this exact problem.

Start by creating a BehaviorSubject in the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Then inject this service into each component and subscribe to the observable.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

You can change the value from either component and the value will be updated, even if you don't have the parent/child relationship.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting the expected value when you console log from selectItem? It looks like you have the subscribe pattern correct.

Comment: yes, I have an array of 2 object as expected. And in doubt, I have too hard coded the array in changeMessage in company.component. But same, I go well in changeMessage but nothing is triggered next.

Comment: I've tried with rxjs/Subject instead rxjs/BehaviorSubject as angular's doc example but it's worst (nothing is fired).

Comment: Ok, after many research, I have declared SrvCompany as provider twice and so I don't have a singleton of this... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't think of that. Glad it helped.

Comment: I went with this example, with data service defined in providers in both components and it didn't also work. However, when I removed service from providers in components and put them inside main module providers everything worked accordingly. Hope it helps!

Comment: @JeffD23 So i didn't use rxjs but i created a common service and its an empty array from my components i will push data to the array.But on reload my service value gets resets ? So if i use rxjs will there be any chance that service value stays in memory since i will be subscribed to it ? I have my simple app running on this url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/data-sharing-service

Comment: I believe I followed your instructions, but when the child is opened it displays 'default message'. Is the problem that the parent is not inserting the message into the service.  Please forgive me, I am a total newbie.

Answer (score 0):

if component are not related than you need use Service

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: <my-astronaut /> is referenced in template of <mission-control />, so there is related component.

Comment: its example but concept is same. try with service and if you face issue comment here

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this.

1. This can be done through shared service by using observable's.
2. You can use ngrx/store for this. This is similar to Redux arch. You will be getting data from state.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the simplest example of sharing data between two independent components, using event emitter and service**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858648/8300620

Answer (score 0):

When you mention non related components, I'm gonna assume that they don't have any parent component. If assumption isn't correct, feel free to [read another of my answers where both cases are addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62755322/5675325).

So, as there's no common parent, we can use an injectable service. In this case, simply inject the service in the components and subscribe to its events.

(Just like the next image shows - [taken from here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) - except that we'll inject the service in two Components)

[image: Inject Service in Component Angular]

The documentation explains it quite well how to [Create and register an injectable service](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#create-and-register-an-injectable-service).

Comment: So on page refresh, all data will be lost? how to keep the data even if a page is refreshed?