# How to call header component function to another component in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to call `showmodel(displayType)`  from another compoent.How to call header component function to another component?

**header.compoent.ts**

```
    import { Component,Renderer } from '@angular/core';
    import { Title,DOCUMENT  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { CountriesService } from '../services/countries.services';
    import { Router,ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
    import {  AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {FacebookService, InitParams, LoginResponse,LoginOptions} from 'ngx-facebook';


    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
    })
    export class HeaderComponent {    


        public visible = false;
        public visibleAnimate = false;
        public visibleRegister = false;
        public visibleAnimateRegister = false;

        registerformcont= false;
        registerActive = true;
        loginactive = false;
        currentUser: any = {};
        PopupTitle='';
        callBackfunc='';
        responseNameCheck:any={};
        LoginOptions:any={};
        response:any={};
        FacebookResponse:any={};

     constructor(
            title: Title,
            private countriesService: CountriesService,
            private Router: Router,
            private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,   
            private fb: FacebookService

     ) {  

        let initParams: InitParams = {
          appId      : '*********',
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.8'
        };

        fb.init(initParams);

            Router.events.subscribe((val) => {
                 this.searchResultCont  = false;    
                  this.showStyle = false;  
                });
     }

    ngOnInit() {    

            this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            if(this.currentUser){
                this.loginStatus = this.currentUser.status;
            }
    }




        public showmodel(displayType): void {


            this.visible = true;                    
            this.visibleAnimate = true

      }


      public hide(): void {
          this.visibleAnimate = false;          
          setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);      
      }



    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 @Component({ 
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
    <app-footer></app-footer>`,
  styleUrls: ['../app/app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent { 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make use of viewChild in your parent component.

in your app component -

```
@ViewChild(HeaderComponent) headerComponent : HeaderComponent;
```

then use

```
headerComponent.headerMethodName();
```

any method from HeaderComponent you want to invoke.

Comment: im getting `[ts] Property 'showmodel' does not exist on type 'typeof HeaderComponent'.` error

Comment: where i have to use headerComponent.headerMethodName();

Answer (score 9):

if there is no direct parent child relation between this two, you've got to use a shared service and an eventEmitter to pass values.

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
})

export class HeaderComponent {    
  this.subs    
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService){

  this.subs = this.sharedService.onHide$.subscribe(()=>{ 
      this.hide(); 
    });
  }
}
```

And then your SharedService is :

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  public onHide$ = new EventEmitter<boolean>()
}

@Component({})
export class YourOtherComponent{
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService){ }

  hideIt(){
    this.sharedService.onHide$.emit('hide it baby')
  }
}
```

Angular `Services` are always the best option (and sometimes the only option) when it comes to component communication.

With above service, component's who can hide your header don't have to know about each other and you can make them completely reusable.

And, don't forget to unsubscribe from your services if your component is destroyed.

inside any of the components who subscribe to `SharedService`'s `$onHide` method.

```
ngOndestroy(){
  this.subs.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect way to get data from one independent component to other.

Comment: Nice answer. very helpful

Comment: So on page refresh, all data will be lost? how to keep the data even if a page is refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `EventEmitter`.

```
@component({
  selector:'app-header',
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  public showmodel(displayType): void {
        this.visible = true;                    
        this.visibleAnimate = true
  }

}
```

Now say in second component you emit the event on a button click.

```
@component({
  selector:'another component',
  template: `<button (click)="callShowModel()">click</button>`
)
export class com2{
  @Output() evt = new EventEmitter();
  callShowModel(){
     this.evt.emit(<value>);
  }
}
```

Now your event can be hooked up in parent component

```
<headercomponent (evt)="showmodel($event)"></headercomponent>
```

Comment: I tried like this. the `console.log(this.evt);` it retun `EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false…}
closed
:
false
hasError
:
false
isStopped
:
false
observers
:
Array(0)
thrownError
:
null
__isAsync
:
false
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Subject`

Comment: Did you import eventemitter ? `import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Yes. i imported all the things

Comment: `(evt)="com1.showmodel($event)"` where its come from `com1`?

Comment: com1 should be the component selector where actual function exists,in this case selector for header component

Comment: `(evt)="app-header.showmodel($event)` this is fine?

Comment: If both of your components are siblings no need to use selector,see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148105/discussion-between-vel-and-neel).

Answer (score 0):

As Angular 2 is based on components and component interaction, it is important to understand how data is passed from one component to another. Data is passed between components using property bindings. Take a look at the syntax below:

```
<user [value]="user"></user>
```

value is a property of current component and user is a property for access another component

you should use to @Input property

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/angular2'

export Class exampleComponent{
  @Input() user: any ;
}
```

Comment: I want to call function from one component to another component.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code: in your  component

**@ViewChild(HeaderComponent, { static: true }) headerComponent: HeaderComponent;**

and then use:

**this.headerComponent.anyheaderMethod();**

this will help definitly

Comment: It is very late answer.