# Angular Material 2 how to update table data after edit without refreshing page?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I used angular material 2 to display a table of data as an order each row. I instantiated `currentTradesData = new MatTableDataSource();` then initialize it in `ngOnInit`. The next action is when I cancel an order, the api returned a successful result, but that order row still shows `cancel button` in `status` cell instead of showing `closed` there, even thought I called method `updateTableData` to reinitialize the data source.

Below is my code:

order-history.component.ts:

```
export class OrderHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  openColumns = ['amount', 'status'];
  resultsLength = 0;
  pageSize = 5;

  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  currentTradesData = new MatTableDataSource();    
  currentTrades: Trades[] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTrades();
  }

  getTrades() {
    this.apiService.getTrades().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.currentTrades = data;
      this.currentTradesData.data = this.currentTrades;
      this.resultsLength = this.currentTradesData.data.length;
    }, error => {console.log(error); });
  }

  cancelTrade(id) {
    this.apiService.cancelTrade(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.updateTableData(data, id);
      this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }, error => {console.log(error); });
  }

  private updateTableData(data: any[], id) {
    const index = this.currentTrades.findIndex(x => x.id = id);
    this.currentTrades[index].isClosed = true;

    this.currentTradesData = data && data.length ? new MatTableDataSource(data)
      : new MatTableDataSource(this.currentTrades);

    this.resultsLength = this.currentTradesData.data.length;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.currentTradesData.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.currentTradesData.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

view:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="currentTradesData" matSort>
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="openColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: openColumns;"></mat-row>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.amount}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-center">
              <button mat-raised-button class="cancel-btn" *ngIf="!row.isClosed" (click)="cancelTrade(row.id)" color="warn">
                Cancel
              </button>
              <span *ngIf="row.isClosed == true">
                <mat-chip color="primary" selected="true">Closed</mat-chip>
              </span>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container> 
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSize]="pageSize" [length]="resultsLength"></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are unable to update the Datasource of the grid may this link will help you out got through it and let me know if got any issue

[Angular + Material - How To Refresh A Data Source (mat-table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746598/angular-material-how-to-refresh-a-data-source-mat-table)