# How to filter OUT a single value but show everything else using Angular 5 and Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've tried this: [Angular + Material - How To Refresh A Data Source (mat-table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746598/angular-material-how-to-refresh-a-data-source-mat-table) and it works, too well, actually!

I want to filter OUT a value and show all others, but this is doing the reverse.

```
applyFilter("INACTIVE"); <-- This only "SHOWS", of course, all INACTIVE records, but I want the opposite.


applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  filterValue = filterValue.trim();
  //filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  this.applicationList.filter = filterValue;
}

refresh() {
  this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
}
```

The values I want to show are: IN_PROGRESS, ACTIVE, NEW and the only value I do not want to show is: INACTIVE.

When I call this applyFilter() function, I use the arguement: "INACTIVE" but the result is "ONLY INACTIVE" records... but I want the opposite: Not SHOW the INACTIVE but everything else.

Thank you

Comment: The documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) says: *To override how data objects match to this filter string, provide a custom function for filterPredicate.*

Comment: So, how do I input, as an argument, IN_PROGRESS, SIGNED, ACTIVE while not showing "INACTIVE"? This link is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the opposite in your function .

Since when you use filter function , it returns the filtered objects..
for example

let us assume you have an array of objects like this

array = [
{ id : 1,
  name : 'name1',
  address : 'usa'
},
{ id : 2,
  name : 'name2',
  address : 'canada'
},
{ id : 3,
  name : 'name3',
  address : 'australia'
}
];

to get everything except user with id 2
you can do something like this

array = array.filter( x => x.name !== 'name2' );

This will return for you the array , without name2.

I Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: YAY! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that... THANKS AGAIN