# Making a dynamic mat-table for mutable dataArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm building a simple angular webapp (front only). How can I make a mat-table renders each time my array changes

my component:

```js
export class TableViewComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Process>;
  processes: Process[];

  constructor(private processesService: ProcessesService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProcesses();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.processes);
    //HERE I'ld like to watch for this.processes changes and change datasource
  }

  getProcesses(): void {
    this.processes = this.processesService.getProcesses();
  }

}
```

I've found a lot of solution but with old versions of angular that used deprecated functions. The Idea is to get a callback when array is updated to refresh table

Comment: no help from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746598/angular-material-how-to-refresh-a-data-source-mat-table

Comment: Nope i've already Seen it

Comment: But I solved the problem passing my data through an input variable in a new Component. Like that Angular render the table himself