# Dynamically editing/deleting data with Angular material i.e. dataSource refresh

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, angular-material, datasource, material-table

I have an angular 7 material project that requires me to display a list of cars in Angular material table. The cars are populated from asp.net core back end.
So far, everything works as it should except for dynamically altering/deleting cars, and having the changes implemented on the fly. Essentially, I'm trying to refresh the data source.

I've followed an example from this site => [Angular + Material - How To Refresh A Data Source (mat-table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746598/angular-material-how-to-refresh-a-data-source-mat-table) but with no success.

Where am I going wrong?

So far, what I've tried is using this code to refresh the `getAllCars()` function and the edit and delete functions:

`this.datasource.connect().next(res);`
and tried:
`this.carModels= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.carModels);`

> Service

```
  removeCarModel(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(this.URL+ 'cars/deleteCar/' + id);
  }

 getAllCarModels() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL+ `cars/getAllCars`);
  }
```

> TS file

```
getAllCars() {
    this.carService.getAllCarModels().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.carModels = res;
        this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = res;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

        // Tried the below. They don't work
        // this.carModels = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.carModels );
        // this.datasource.connect().next(res);

      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    );
  }
```

> Remove Car

```
removeCar: any;
  removeSelectedCar(id) {
      this.carService.removeCarModel(id).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.removeCar = res;

         // Tried the below. They don't work
         // this.dataSource.connect().next(res);
         // this.removeCar= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.removeCar);

          console.log("Successfully deleted");
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error");
        }
      );
  }

editCar: any;
  editSelectedCar() {
    this.carService.editCarModel(this.Id, this.carModel).subscribe(res=> {
    console.log("Successfully edited");
    this.editCar = res;

 // Tried the below. They don't work
         // this.dataSource.connect().next(res);
         // this.editCar = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.editCar);

    }, error => {
      console.log("Error");
    }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the `mat-table` connects with the DataSource, you can only provide new information though the DataSource itself.

I encourage you to use `@matheo/datasource` to have clean separation of concerns, manipulate your data only in the corresponding services (database and datasource) without worries about new features to implement, and just calling `reload()` when you need to refresh the list after some edition/deletion.

I wrote about this library and built a friendly demo:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6

I can support your use case if you like it.
Happy coding!