# Can't pass data from Child to Parent using @ViewChild Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, parent-child, viewchild

Hi I can't pass my data from child to parent using @ViewChild

I have this code from

**admin-layout.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(TribeComponent)
 getRoute :TribeComponent; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log( this.getRoute);
  this.message = this.getRoute.messagetwo;
  console.log('Values on ngAfterViewInit():');
  console.log("primaryColorSample:", this.message);
}
```

and code from

**tribecomponent.ts**

```
messagetwo:string = "true";
```

the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'messagetwo' of undefined
at AdminLayoutComponent.push../src/app/layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts.AdminLayoutComponent.ngAfterViewInit (admin-layout.component.ts:45)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22416)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:22390)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:22380)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23316)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
```

the first console was undefined `console.log( this.getRoute);`

the second one was the error above `console.log("primaryColorSample:", this.message);`

btw admin-layout is kind of my app component html so I use router outlet to navigate to tribe component. Is it the reason why it can't see tribe as its child?
here's a sample how my layout work [Creative Tim's Argon Dashboard Angular](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-dashboard-angular)

Comment: Do you have any `*ngIf` in your template above the child you are querying?

Comment: no I don't have @Reactgular

Comment: Does your template have `<ng-content>` because you need to use `@ContentChild` instead for that.

Comment: @Reactgular how do I use it?

Comment: i investigated your project structure and [admin-layout.component](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-dashboard-angular/blob/master/src/app/layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html) doesn't have `TribeComponent` neither as ViewChild nor as ContentChild. It is placed under router-outlet and it becomes a child of  `admin-layout.component` in DOM tree not in Angular's View Hierarchy. There is a [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842) about this. And there is a good explanation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842#issuecomment-470167258)

Comment: since those two component doesn't have a direct parent/child relationship. you cannot use Input/Output mechanics or View/Content queries. you need a broker service to share data. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414226/angular-4-pass-data-between-2-not-related-components) on how you can do it.

Comment: @ysf you should've answered it I found the solution thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To send data from child to parent use events (not ViewChild) - e.g in child:

```
@Output() public myevent = new EventEmitter<any>();

...
fireEvent() {
  this.myevent.emit({'some':'data'});
}
```

and in parent template

```
<child-component (myevent)="handleEvent($event)">...</child-component>
```

where `handleEvent(data)` is your pratent function which will get emited data from child

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-tribe' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-tribe' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Comment: you have some problem with you component (not events) - write separate question on stackoverflow about it

Comment: please see the file structure via the link I provided