# Share the value between two components as the first component get executed before

Tags: angular

I have two components `navbarcomponent` and `logincomponent`.

```
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-login></app-login>
```

`navbarcomponent` get executed before the `logincomponent`. 
In my `logincomponent` while the user login i set the the user informations in local storage.
and i'm calling it in ngoninit of my `navbarcomponent`.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.user = localStorage.getItem("user");
}
```

But the user variable is always null . because it get executed before the `logincomponent` instantiate it.

Is there a way to get the value after the method in login get executed ?

Comment: both these are child components?

Comment: yes both of them are child of app.component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 pass data between 2 not related components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414226/angular-4-pass-data-between-2-not-related-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a service for sharing data between 2 components.

```
export class CheckLoginService {
    public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    callLoadData(value: boolean) {
        this.status.next(value);
    }
}
```

NavbarComponent :

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private checkLoginService: CheckLoginService) { }
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false
  sessionFirstName: string


  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkLogin()
    this.checkLoginService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      if (val == true) {
        this.sessionFirstName = localStorage.getItem('sessionFirstName');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

LoginComponent

```
login(user:any) {
    localStorage.setItem('sessionFirstName', user.userFirstName)
    this.checkLoginService.callLoadData(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `EventEmitter` and `Input` to update the value between two child components.

**Login.Component.ts**

```
@Output() updateUserNameEmitter = new EventEmitter();

login(){
  this.updateUserNameEmitter.emit(localStorage.getItem("user");)
}
```

**App.component.html**

```
<app-login (updateUserNameEmitter)="updateUserName($event)"></app-login>
<app-navbar [userName]="userName"></app-navbar>
```

**App.Component.ts**

```
public userName: string;

updateUserName(userName){
 this.userName = userName;
}
```

Comment: This is a simpler way to share data if both the components are child of same parent component. However for login case, its better to create a service as logout can occur from other services as well such as from httpinterceptor service on token expiration, For updating navbar at that time service is needed

Comment: @AdritaSharma yea agree.