# How can I allow an output event from one Angular element to update the value of another Angular element?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

**Please note that this question has to do with Angular Elements, which is detailed [here](https://angular.io/guide/elements). This functionality allows for the creation of HTML elements from compiled Angular components.**

I am working on modernizing an old web application piece-by-piece. The target framework is Angular, and so to ease the transition we are creating Angular elements to replace difference pieces of our old code.

The basic structure is as follows: I have a `menu-bar` component whose output I want to use to update a `content` component.

**menu-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './menu-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-bar.component.css']
})
export class MenuBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() menuItemId = new EventEmitter()

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendId(id: number) {
    console.log(id)
    this.menuItemId.emit(id)
  }
}
```

**content.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { Data } from '../../classes/data.model';
import * as chemReact from '../../classes/reactionResult.model';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() initialContentId: number;

  initialContent: Data;

  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("Content ID was changed to " + this.initialContentId)

    this.httpService.getData(this.initialContentId)
      .subscribe(c => {
        console.log("Returned from subscription")
        this.initialContent = Object.assign(new Data(), c);
        console.log("Initial content is " + this.initialContent.name);
        this.initialContent.createdData.subscribe(data =>
            console.log("Created Data is " + data))
        this.substances.push(this.initialContent);
      });
  }
}
```

When running the Angular project as a standalone app, this works properly. However, after I've exported the components as elements and included them in my legacy project:

```
<div class="menu">
    <menu-bar></menu-bar>
</div>
<div class="main" id="main-container">
    <content
        initialContentId="menuItemId"></content>
</div>

<script>
    const component1 = document.querySelector('menu-bar');
    component1.addEventListener('menuItemId', (event) => {
        const component2 = document.querySelector('content')
        console.log("Changing content ID to " + event.detail)
        component2.initialContentId= event.detail
    })
</script>
```

the `content` control does not update when the input is changed.

## Possibly Helpful Information

- When I click on an item in the menu component, all of my console logging statements get called, so I know I'm properly receiving and then sending the event.
- Say I click "Menu Item 1". When I click "Menu Item 2", the results I expect for "Menu Item 1" will show up in the control. So I know that the content component is getting the data set, it's just not updating when I expect it to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 pass data between 2 not related components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414226/angular-4-pass-data-between-2-not-related-components)

Comment: Look into `@Input`, `@ Output` and `EventEmitter`