# Render delay for *ngIf due to filters causing expression change - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.
```

I am getting the above "warning" in console. I have a bunch of filters that hide/show items in the `ngFor` loop. When the filters do not get a match e.g. no `ngFor` children I prompt `ngIf` to display a graceful message.

This is how I do it...

**Component.ts**

```
<!-- Returned contact logs -->
<ul #personTimeline>
  <my-timeline-entry
    *ngFor="let entry of contactLog | filter:filteredContactReason:'contactReason'"
    logEntryDateTime={{entry.dateTime}} logEntryNotes={{entry.notes}}>
  </my-timeline-entry>
</ul>


<!-- No results returned -->
<div *ngIf="!personTimeline.children.length">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
      <strong>{{startDate}} Sorry!{{' '}}</strong>No contact log matches found.
    </div>
</div>
```

By using `#personTimeline` I check its children.length. When '0' it displays my no results div.

I've changed a few things, and refactored some code, now this message only appears when I make an interaction "after" first seeing a blank space where I should see the no results div. As soon as I click an element the no results message appears.

I know I probably need to introduce `ngOnChanges`? as this is a lifecycle issue, But not sure how to target my `#personTimeline` handle or do I need to trigger `*ngIf="!personTimeline.children.length"` somehow through that handle?

Or is there a better way to implement showing no results?

Any help or advise is appreciated as always.

Comment: I see some ideas of markForCheck, wondering if this could be a option here?

Comment: Using markForCheck is great inside of the ts file. If you're doing this all in the html it wouldn't work as well. If you comment out your no-results div does your error go away? Usually this type of error has to do with changing information while the angular is detecting all changes.

Comment: Yes the error does go away if I comment out the no-results div

Answer (score 1):

There's a beautiful explanation on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061845/9045615

Basically, this is happening because, in development mode the Angular's change detection adds an additional check after every regular change detection to check if any value, model or any property has changed between the two change detection mechanisms.

But, I've a quick fix/hack for you using *ChangeDetectionRef*:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class Component implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  // Try ngAfterContentInit  if ngAFterViewInit() doesn't work for you.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Other article to read: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef.

Comment: Unfortunately neither options worked in my case - thanks for the link