# Make a change in an Angular service show up in all of the components that use that service

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, service

I am building the clone of a website/app called Kualitee.com. It is a test-management tool used by QA Engineers.
In kualitee, you have multiple projects, with test cases and members. You can add, delete, and change projects and members. There is a header on top which enables you to select a project of which you want the data of i.e test cases and stuff.

[the header for changing projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULmJv.jpg)

The approach I used for this is as follow:

**1. one service containing all the data**

**2. one service containing only the project selected...**

The whole app uses the data found in the second service. When I make a change in a project, say add a new member, it does display that at that time. After that, if I change the project in the select at the top to another project, the component containing that member does not change, even though the project is a different one now, but as soon as I switch to another component, through routing, and back again, the changes are there.

My point is, is there any way I can add functionality where, if a parent component changes an object in service, the change reflects in a child component also using that same object in that same service, without me needing to change components or refresh.

**PS. This is my first time asking something on StackOverflow, Sorry if my question is confusing.**

Comment: You should show us some code. 

Definitely the component and the seconds service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an observable shared service to share the data between components. Here is how to achieve that: [Interaction between components using a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958836/angular2-interaction-between-components-using-a-service/41960007#41960007)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referred to Angular life cycle https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I checked it out, and it worked perfectly. Just needed to add a ngAfterContentChecked function to update the data recieved from the service. Thanks a lot, not sure why lifecycle methods did not come to mind...