# Passing object from one component to another component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-components

I am working in Angular 7 . 
where I am passing object to another component , I am doing it using @input decorative , but components are siblings , 
        so How I can pass the object to another component

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954484/communicate-between-two-child-components-in-angular-2 .Version may change but the technique is same.

Answer (score 1):

It is better use Service for the communication in this scenario.

In service u can use Subject which can act as both observer and observable.

ex.

In Service

```
  someSubject = new Subject<any>();
```

In component one

```
 someService.someSubject.next(objectUWantToSend);
```

In Component two u can subscribe or vise versa

```
someService.someSubject.subscribe((receiveObjectHere) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

@input decorative can only be used for passing values from parent to child components.

For communication between siblings or any components use rxjs subject and Observable instead.

You can follow this - 
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject