# How to send object from parent to child component - it become undefined after routing parent to child

Tags: angular

I have one list Client list (agGrid) is used. on click, it navigates to editClient form aka childComponent. How can I pass the whole object from that client list component to edit client from the component? Please let me know the best way to do..

below is the object I want to pass

```
{
    "ClientTypeId": "3",
    "IsActive": "1",
    "CompByName": "Administration",
    "RTId": "8",
    "ALToName": "Sam Artho",
    "IsSecured": "1",
    "Status": null,
    "TTQStatus": "Active",
    "StsId": null,
    "ttqId": "3486",
    "FName": "Quto Iva",
    "ContactNo": "1111111111",
    "ACTTo": "8",
    "ACTBy": "4",
    "CrDate": "22/10/2021",
    "ModBy": "0",
    "ModDate": "",
    "Remark": " ",
    "IsView": "2"
}
```

I could get this object on the edit button click.

Comment: You would have to keep the object in state via a service, ngrx, etc, so that when you navigate, your child component can retrieve the item and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to achieve that this way:

1. Create a service. (`ng g s <service-name>`)
2. Put your variables in that service so you can reference them in both pages.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I have found very great solution for this 

this._router.navigateByUrl('/client/edit-client', { state: { editClient } });

I could access the Object on edit-client component by using window.history.state in ngOnInit() 

I think, it would be the best way to get the object/array/.. data on another component, I know the data will have vanished on page refresh but, I think, the service does the same!

Comment: yes you are right but this way also a hacker can access your data using `window` object. It is better to use services to keep data in memory level and make them not accessible. @Raj

Comment: Oh isn't it safe to use? I am using SSL so data will travel in the secure encrypted tunnel!

Comment: Open console and in it if you could log that it is not safe

Comment: You are right! I could access the data using the window object in the console.

Comment: Yes. I think if you use services it will be more secure @Raj

Comment: Thing is that I have already created separate services for both the component... now I have to create one more service called shared service which I can use for both components... I did not want to mess up with the structure so was avoiding it...

Comment: No you can import your child service in parent component and set it there @Raj

Comment: Maybe! that would be the best way... I really appreciate your help @skyBlue

Comment: Cant PetchValue after in subscribe?

fillClientForm() {
    this._manageClientService.mySubject.subscribe
      ((response) => {
        this.client = response
        console.log("edit page", this.client)
        if (this.lead) {
          this.isEditMode = true
          this.addNewLeadFb.patchValue({
            ClientTypeId: this.client.ClientTypeId,
            IsActive: this.client.IsActive,
            ...

Comment: You forgot to add 'asObservable()' before subscribing

Comment: And I think you can patchValue and it os probably a problem with the logic.

Comment: Hmmm... I can not help unless you can provide a stackblitz of this code example

Comment: I simply get the data in the console .. just can't PatchValue! in comon service someSubject = new Subject<any>(); and in component this._addClientService.someSubject.next(editClient); this._router.navigateByUrl('/client/edit-client'); in edit client component: fillClientForm() { this._manageClientService.mySubject.subscribe ((response) => { this.client = response console.log("edit page", this.client) if (this.client) { this.isEditMode = true this.addNewClientFb.patchValue({ ClientTypeId: this.client.ClientTypeId, IsActive: this.client.IsActive, ... –

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624854/17220996

I saw his example and followed it... I think it should work.. @skyBlue

Comment: I did some debug and found the route call after the value is set! How it is possible? any solution? @skyBlue

Comment: Lines will execute one after another. If you want to make it work like after last one finished you can add await

Comment: It's in order already and also tried async-await but nothing worked!

Comment: Wow! I tried settimeout to 5000 and it worked! HOW? await should work!

Comment: Hmmm don't know unless I can debug it myself

Comment: someSubject = new ReplaySubject(1); solved the issue @skyBlue

subject did not work ..looks like it could not able to hold the object...

Comment: That's interesting I will read more about that