# Get URL parameters in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to receive URL parameters of these frames :

"GET /Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8 HTTP/1.1 Host: www.quatuoradbd.com"

or

"GET /Reception/00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef/8 HTTP/1.1 Host: www.quatuoradbd.com"

The host is a example, it is your domaine name

but I do not understand why I can not do it. I use queryParams or snapshot for receiving parameters of URL in function of the frame sent.

Here my project on Github: https://github.com/Sauniere/test

Comment: use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this format "GET /Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8"

```
var q = {
    ID: ID,
    Voltage : Voltage
};
this._router.navigate(['/Reception'], {
    queryParams: q
});
```

And your route will be just 'Reception' in route module

if you want to use another "GET /Reception/00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef/8"
just define Reception/:ID/:Voltage which you're doing.

```
this.ID = this.route.snapshot.params['ID'];
this.Voltage = this.route.snapshot.params['Voltage'];
```

Comment: These frames from a microcontroller. Is it different? Because when I put "http://localhost:4200/Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8" or "http://localhost:4200/Reception/00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef/8" in URL's bar it works fine with snapshot or queryParams. But when I send this frame from microcontroller "GET /Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8 HTTP/1.1 Host: www.quatuoradbd.com" it doesn't work