# Angular 5 - Pass parameter to built angular from server

Tags: angular, build

I developed a simple angular project. by requesting to http://localhost:4200/?u=4, it returns a page that shows data for user with id of 4. Also in server side I have my user_id.

When I build my angular project, index page is something like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bisphone Campaign</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.dc2c24976210846778e8.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.73a44a2a8ff085047495.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.8ca0b37d69dda2b321fe.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

My question is how to call index.html with this **user_id**. The desired system is a page that gets **user_id** and shows page like http://localhost:4200/?u=**user_id**

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 please read this guide about routing..

Comment: @VijaySankhat, I read it, which part must help me?

Comment: 'src/app/app-routing.module.ts (all routes)' please search this string from your browser after going to given link.

Comment: or you can tru this post directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5?rq=1

Comment: I have router in my project, it works perfectly when I serve project with **ng serve**. I can change user_id in http://localhost:4200/?u=user_id and it show data relative to user_id. all of my problem is after build the project (ng build) and I want to know how to call static index.html file to get user_id from server side.

Comment: You can set your home page inside route list no need to call index file in your build. that all stuff will be loaded by Angular itself.

Comment: At server side u don't need to call index page rather than call service call with given user id and you will get this user id at server side where you handle requset...

Comment: @VijaySankhat thanks, really you helped me

Comment: @VijaySankhat Ok, rewrite your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your home page inside route list no need to call index file in your build. that all stuff will be loaded by Angular itself. please refer this link.
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5?rq=1) or [this one](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Comment: This comment helps me : At server side u don't need to call index page rather than call service call with given user id and you will get this user id at server side where you handle requset.