# How to pass object between components when switching between routes Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I have a component which looks like this

```
<div class="animal">
  <a routerLink="/animal/{{animal.id}}">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

It gets `animal` object from parent component, which is just a list of childs.

```
@Input() animal;
```

When I click on it I'm moving to another component where I want to display some propreties from this clicked `animal` object.

I thought of create a service which will store this object but the problem is I don't know how to get only clicked object and not every object from the list.

All the help will be much appreciated.

Comment: there are two ways to pass value, ```path variables``` and ```query params``` check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125257/4294381

Answer (score 2):

You can catch your parameters in your routed Component by using `ActivatedRoute` in `angular`

Your routing path :

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { 
    // Other routes
  },
  {
     path:'animal/:id'
     component : AnimalDetailsComponent
  }
]
```

**animal-details.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) {} 

ngOnInit(){
  this.route.params.subscribe((params)=>{
     console.log(params['id'])
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this way I'm getting an id and not the whole object

Comment: if you want to send whole object, you can either use `EventEmitter` or `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` with the help of `service`. You can also make use of `SessionStorage` or `localStorage` for communication between components.

Comment: Hm, I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39569933/5206428 which works but stops working if I refresh route on `/animal/:id`

Comment: SessionStorage and LocalStorage won’t have such issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using resolver Route Resolver Service - where you can do some action before the routing loads

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: Component,
    resolve: { service: Service },
  },

export class Service implements Resolve<object | string> {

  constructor() {
    }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<object | string> | Promise<object | string>  {
        return {};
    }
```

In your onInit you can read the data by injecting a ActivatedRoute service in your component constructor like this

```
constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }
```

Code in Onint - `this.variable = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data["service"];`