# How to create a method in Angular 6 that returns a queryParams from the url?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code. Is there any other better or best way to get the queryParams from the url?

```
  getSolutionId(){
    let solutionId: number;
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => {
      solutionId = queryParams.solutionId ? queryParams.solutionId: null;
    });
    return solutionId;
  }
```

Comment: you cannot do this in that way

Comment: But how can i do it? I am new to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already answered by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808539/10747134) that also references [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) describing how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You use the router snapshot:

```
getSolutionId() {
   return this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.solutionId;
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#queryParamMap

Comment: These returns an error. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ParamMap' has no compatible call signatures

Comment: @C.EJames you're using the ActivatedRoute class? https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Yes I imported it

Comment: @C.EJames sorry, I thought the queryParamMap was a function. Try it as a property. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.param = params['name'];

    }).unsubscribe();
  }
```

This is case sensitive

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure in what terms you are asking to get query params.

Assuming you are trying to create some global method to get queryParams if any. you can call method on every router chang like this -

```
this.router.events.subscribe(route => {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => {
      solutionId = queryParams.solutionId || null;
    });
});
```

Comment: This will leak memory badly, because you are constantly subscribing on every router event.

Comment: Yes, As I already mentioned in the answer, assuming to trigger queryParams on every router change globally.

Comment: Update the code with `queryParams.pipe(first()).subscribe(...)`.

Comment: @cgTag Can you please update my answer? I haven't used `queryParams.pipe..` yet