# How can i access my "access_token" from localhost url?

Tags: angular, token

I need to access "access_token" from localhost URL.

Example:

http://localhost:4200/#access_token=BQAJM4v-EpUnX2etRBh_5NJCVbxeR4nUp9pYfq4I7K77kRV80tukoEAusMfp6jWbypSx7e-F6NhEuNWlDERO1faVJaIgCwkTFeCQxmdsSW7cHRIYR05InAVsyDgKOQNDXyfECQq71Gf56Oss15ysSU3UxyxSgWV4y2__sn0P33dO60N3UtWvKoe9WXzrx3hshBQjYJD2n_8HUBF9fG2gjH0WrChwlwjzIzy6FyFDyT4-wSIxudVtXMBclpHcBJ9LEIuVDtVphITW0Dq3XUcq1VHKQIzY2vi-ufnzlA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=

I would like to get:

"BQAJM4v-EpUnX2etRBh_5NJCVbxeR4nUp9pYfq4I7K77kRV80tukoEAusMfp6jWbypSx7e-F6NhEuNWlDERO1faVJaIgCwkTFeCQxmdsSW7cHRIYR05InAVsyDgKOQNDXyfECQq71Gf56Oss15ysSU3UxyxSgWV4y2__sn0P33dO60N3UtWvKoe9WXzrx3hshBQjYJD2n_8HUBF9fG2gjH0WrChwlwjzIzy6FyFDyT4-wSIxudVtXMBclpHcBJ9LEIuVDtVphITW0Dq3XUcq1VHKQIzY2vi-ufnzlA"

into a variable, so I can use this for my API calls instead of hardcoding an access token.

how can I do using angular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get query parameters from URL in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 0):

you can use native js lication api `location.hash.slice(1).split('&').map(pair => pair.split('=')).find(([key]) => key === 'access_token')[1]`

Comment: sorry, I'm new to angular how can I use that?

Comment: use constructor to inject dependencies `constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router){};`

Comment: ok so injected router into the constructor, then tried to console log. let myToken = router.parseUrl(location.href).queryParamMap.get('access_token'). But it comes out as null

Comment: you are right, i missread a few symbols in the question. Sorry for that. Fixed the answer for now.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got it. Used hash = hash.slice(0, -41) to get rid of "&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state="

Comment: fixed anwswer again to handle such cases