# Angular 6 application to read parameters from an external calling application

Tags: angular, angular6

We have a portal which is a non-angular application. The portal redirects to my Angular 6 application on click of a some link.
While redirecting it will send a JWT token as a parameter.
Now my issues is that i want to read this token and send it to the backend api service for authentication so that appropriate pages are displayed to the authorized users.
How can i read this token in my angular 6?

Comment: While redirecting, how is it sending JWT token as a parameter? query parameter or as part of the header? please post a sample of redirect URL and headers.

Comment: It will be sent as a parameter http://myApp?token=someJwtToken&userId=12345

Comment: Sorry i do not have the sample of redirect URL as I it is being taken care by another developer. All i know is that the token will come as a parameter.

Comment: in that case, refer answers for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try the suggested solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are redirecting like `https://xxxxx.com/angular?jwt=XXXXX`

so get the parm in component using the activated route

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); // {jwo: "XXXXXX"}
         // call auth service to check user is logged in or not
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same approach, By check the token in `CanActivate` in `authguard` you can check access for this token then allowed user to navigate to route or not
here is an example:

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  let accesstoken: string = next.queryParams.accesstoken;
  if (this.authService.IsAuthenticated) {
    let user = this.authService.GetUser();
    let CurrentDate = new Date();
    let date = CurrentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + CurrentDate.getDate();
    if (Date.parse(date) <= Date.parse(user.expire_date)) {
      if (accesstoken) {
        // if token in url, redirect to url without token :)
        if (user.uuid == accesstoken)
          this.router.navigateByUrl(window.location.pathname);
        // if new token is not the same of current one, Register with new token
        else {
          return this.authService.checkAccess(accesstoken).pipe(
            map(data => {
              if (data === true) {
                if (accesstoken) {
                  this.router.navigateByUrl(window.location.pathname);
                }
                return true;
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
              }

            })
          );
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    else if (Date.parse(date) > Date.parse(user.expire_date)) {
      return this.authService.checkAccess(accesstoken).pipe(
        map(data => {
          if (data === true) {
            if (accesstoken) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl(window.location.pathname);
            }
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }

        })
      );
    }

  } // End of authenticated with check validty
  else if (!NOU(accesstoken)) { // In case current registered token is not valid, CheckAccess with new token
    this.authService.checkAccess(accesstoken).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data === true) {
          if (accesstoken) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(window.location.pathname);
          }
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

}
```

assuming that when login user successfully, you store `token` and `expire_date` in `localstorage` and set a property `IsAuthenticated` to `true`
So first check if user is already authenticated then check validity by comparing token with its expire_date but in Case using `jwt` I think there is different way to know if token still valid or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using snapshot you can get the params from URL.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.snapshot.queryParams['paramName'];
 }
```