# How to open nebular "stepper" depends on query params?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to open nebular 'stepper' step, which depends on query params.
For example: if route is /products/create?step=third shoud open third step

```
<nb-stepper [selected]="'second'">
  <nb-step [stepControl]="firstForm" [label]="first" #first>
   first
  </nb-step>
  <nb-step [label]="second" #second>
    second
  </nb-step>
  <nb-step [label]="third" #third>
    third
    <ng-template #third>Third step</ng-template>
  </nb-step>
</nb-stepper>
```

i have tried to use selected property, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get query params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808539/5621827) in your component  and use that param to set selected step so in your compoenent

```
selectedStep='second';

constructor(activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data)=>{
if(data['step']){
this.selectedStep =data['step']
}
})
}
```

and in html

```
<nb-stepper [selected]="selectedStep">
```

Comment: property should be **[(selectedIndex)]** not **[selected]**

but it doesn't work for me in either case.