# How do I read the values from query string in angular 5?

Tags: angular, query-string

how to read values from query string in angular 5

the url format is following
https://www.test.com/test?id=13467tdgbgfhjfgy

Comment: Please share code where you tried so we can guide you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get query parameters from URL in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component, you can access to query parameters with **ActivatedRoute**.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['id']); // 13467tdgbgfhjfgy
  });
}
```

https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/