# angular 6 url with query string not matching path

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have below config

```
 { path:'test/display/:mode' ,component:DisplayComponent }
```

This is working if i call like

> test/display/5

But it not able to find matching route when i give

> test/display/?mode=5

I am not able to figure how to make it

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to pass a parameter as a Query String?

Comment: @SuhasMandumale, I am getting this url from another app

Comment: Try this: `this.route.navigateByUrl("/test/display?mode=5");`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, what does this mean? I am getting this url from other app

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam got it you want to allow this url which serve's your component? Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, yes

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam If possible provide stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your routes differently (auxilary) for both the options:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'test/:mode', component: TestComponent }, // for path variables
    { path: 'test', component: TestComponent }  // for query params
];
```

For the first one your url will look like:

```
http://localhost:4200/test/20
```

and for the second one:

```
http://localhost:4200/test?mode=20
```

And then use `queryParams` to read the values:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params['mode']);
    });
}
```

Comment: It will have http://localhost:4200/test/?mode=20, (/ before > ?)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, once the url is consumed by Angular, '/' is removed. I am able to navigate to the page with or without '/'.

Comment: I am not able to do that, it is removing / from url, the url should persist,

Comment: I don't understand, will there be a problem if the '/' is not there? What are you trying to achieve? If just resolving the route is the problem, then above works. Please let me know if you are trying something else?

Comment: yes, i am injecting angular app to .net mvc for a single page, so url should be intact

Comment: Ok, you see, the URL manipulation is happening only on the UI app, and if you have to communicate with your .Net app, you can do that manually, or if you need it for all such URLs, you can write an interceptor to add '/' to the URL before sending it out or the Angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not the same, declaring **:mode** in your router config tells Angular that you are declaring an angular *route parameter*, by setting **?mode=5** in the url you are declaring a *query parameter*. These are handled differently.

Good stackoverflow article on how to use query parameter:
[How to get query parameters from URL in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    if(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('mode')){
        // if mode 
    }else {
        // if not mode
    }
}
```

`{ path:'test/display' ,component:DisplayComponent }`

Answer (score 0):

The route specifies that it must have a mode parameter on the end, so the alternative form without a mode parameter at the end of the path, is different.

```
{ path:'test/display/:mode' ,component:DisplayComponent }
```

if different to:

```
{ path:'test/display/' ,component:DisplayComponent }
```

The query string is not part of the route at all, so adding one is not the equivalent of ":mode".

So, you simply need to specify both of these alternative routes if you want to support route parameters and query strings. Generally it's best practice to use route parameters only for required parameters such as the id of a resource you are requesting/updating. Query string parameters are best used for optional parameters, such as search options, data windowing, or algorithm tweaks.

```
[{ path:'test/display/:mode' ,component:DisplayComponent },
{ path:'test/display/' ,component:DisplayComponent }]
```

is what you want. Then you can

> test/display/5

and

> test/display/?mode=5

To obtain the query string value you need to subscribe to the queryParams of the activatedRoute service.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public mode = null;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((qp: Params) => {
        this.mode = qp['mode'];

    });
  }
}
```