# Get two parameters from URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form which takes one parameter to construct and link a customer to a product. Now we have added another parameter to include in the URL however I can't seem to get it from the URL.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help!

URL: http://localhost:4200/check/98712?Id=803

I can manage to get the first parameter out "98712" but not the Id.

In my app.module under

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{ path: 'check/:cust', component: CheckComponent},
```

I have tried to ad Id there but it doesn't work.

In my Check component I'm taking out the customer and the Id but still the Id is empty.

```
this.customer = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('cust'); 
this.Ids = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('Id'); //Ids since it could be several, hence the add of Id in the URL
```

My routes in app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'ms', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'ms', component: CheckComponent },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `id` is a query parameter, so you need to get it from `queryParamMap`.

```js
this.customer = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('cust'); 
this.Ids = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('Id');
```

Comment: You are a hero! I was blindsided here, totally missed that. Will mark as answer as soon as I can. Thanks