# Loop on an object

Tags: angular

In the `internal-transfer-details` page, I have a table with two columns: I have a numerical value and a hyperlink.

[illustration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaEnp.png)

[illustration2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUzSQ.png)

If I click on the first link, I want to retrieve in the HTML table, the value `840`.

I get to the `internal-transfer-watch` page and I get a lot of rows. I just want to retrieve a row. (the value `840`)

[illustration 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNWn.png)

ID is `347075`

[illustration 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QAhv.png)

The JSON file is [here](https://jsonblob.com/966319018265034752).

**internal-transfert-details.component.ts**  (parent)

```
export class InternalTransfertDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  internalTransfertDetails: InternalTransfertDetails[] = [];

  constructor(private service: InternalTransfertDetailsService, private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTransfert()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  private getTransfert(): void {

    this.service.getTransfert().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        
        this.internalTransfertDetails = res.TRANS.map(
          internalTransfertLine => {
            return {
              titre: {
                label: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.LABEL,
                isin: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.ISIN,
                svm: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.SVM,
              },
              solde: internalTransfertLine.SOLDE,
              qte_vente: internalTransfertLine.QTE_VENTE,
              qte_bloq: internalTransfertLine.QTE_BLOQ,
              qte_trf: internalTransfertLine.QTE_TRF
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**internal-transfert-details.component.html**

```
<div class="home-content">
  <div class="container" *ngIf="internalTransfertDetails">
    <div class="pt-50">
      <h1 class="text-center pb-3">Transfert Interne - Details</h1>
      <div class="row pt-3 container">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20%;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <th scope="col">Solde</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr
                  *ngFor="let internalTransfertDetail of internalTransfertDetails"
                >
                  <td scope="row" class="text-end">
                    {{internalTransfertDetail.solde }}
                  </td>
                  <td scope="row " class="text-end">
                    <a
                      [routerLink]="[ '/transferts/internal-transfert-watch/' + internalTransfertDetail.titre.svm ] "
                    >
                      Link
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**internal-transfert-details.response.ts**

```
import { ApiResponse } from "src/shared/types/api.response";

export interface InternalTransfertDetailsResponse extends ApiResponse {
    TRANS: {
        TITRE: {
            LABEL: string,
            ISIN: string,
            SVM: number,
        },
        SOLDE: number,
        QTE_VENTE: number,
        QTE_BLOQ: number,
        QTE_TRF: number,


    }[];
}
```

**internal-transfert-details.ts**

```
export interface InternalTransfertDetails {
    titre: {
        label: string;
        isin: string;
        svm: number;
    },

    solde: number;
    qte_vente: number;
    qte_bloq: number; 
    qte_trf: number; 

}
```

**internal-transfert-watch.component.ts**  (child)

```
export class InternalTransfertWatchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  internalTransfertDetails: InternalTransfertDetails[] = [];

  constructor(private service: InternalTransfertDetailsService, private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTransfert()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  private getTransfert(): void {

    this.service.getTransfert().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        
        this.internalTransfertDetails = res.TRANS.map(
          internalTransfertLine => {
            return {
              titre: {
                label: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.LABEL,
                isin: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.ISIN,
                svm: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.SVM,
              },
              solde: internalTransfertLine.SOLDE,
              qte_vente: internalTransfertLine.QTE_VENTE,
              qte_bloq: internalTransfertLine.QTE_BLOQ,
              qte_trf: internalTransfertLine.QTE_TRF
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**internal-transfert-watch.component.html**

```
<div class="home-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pt-50">
      <h1 class="text-center pb-3">Transfert Interne - Details</h1>
      <div class="row pt-3 container">
        <div class="card" style="width: 30%;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <th scope="col">Solde</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr
                  *ngFor="let internalTransfertDetail of internalTransfertDetails"
                >
                  <td scope="row" class="text-center">
                    {{internalTransfertDetail.solde }}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks you a lot

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: @RF1991: Sorry, I edited my first message, I added the JSON file.

Comment: You are itereting a data using ngFor - since the data itself is an array of objects. This is the correct result. If you need to just see the Nth iteration replace the ngFor with something like myArray[0].data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one line, don't use `ngFor`:

Change

```html
<tr *ngFor="let internalTransfertDetail of internalTransfertDetails">
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{internalTransfertDetail[0].solde }}</td>
</tr>
```

To

```html
<tr>
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{internalTransfertDetails[0].solde }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that if I click on hyperlink #2, I still get the value of the first index in the array.

Comment: I have no idea what hyperlink #2 is, sorry.

Comment: no problem, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what this mysterious hyperlink is in your question...

Comment: I edited my post, normally it's more detailed... Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to navigate to another page that only shows one row, so you should create a new component with an input variable, not edit this one.

Comment: it works !! I added an input it works, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Modify component.ts by adding filter like below.

```
this.internalTransfertDetails = res.TRANS.filter(internalTransfert => internalTransfert.SOLDE == param1).map(
      internalTransfertLine => {
        return {
          titre: {
            label: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.LABEL,
            isin: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.ISIN,
            svm: internalTransfertLine.TITRE.SVM,
          },
          solde: internalTransfertLine.SOLDE,
          qte_vente: internalTransfertLine.QTE_VENTE,
          qte_bloq: internalTransfertLine.QTE_BLOQ,
          qte_trf: internalTransfertLine.QTE_TRF
        }
      }
    );
```

And keep component.html like below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let internalTransfertDetail of internalTransfertDetails">
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">
        {{internalTransfertDetail.solde }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: When,  I open a different hyperlink I always get the value `840`. :-(

Comment: Okay, Then You have to get the solde value from the URL as a query param. You can refer this link for that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5). Then replace that value in my filter method param1. I have edited my answer. Please check filter method and replace param1 with your query param value.

Comment: I added an input, it works now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`internalTransfertDetail` is an object of an array. There's no reason to use the subscript operator here.

```
<tr *ngFor="let internalTransfertDetail of internalTransfertDetails">
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{internalTransfertDetail.solde }}</td>
</tr>
```

Let me know if this helps ^-^