# How to Set ? in routeFile in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My Requirement is From Backend I am getting routes as "app/dashboard?dashboard_id={id}"
How can I configure this in Module.ts file?

I tried using below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "app/dashboard/:dashboard_id",
    component: AddEditComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

but I am getting errors like routes are not defined.

Can Someone Please Help me on that how can I configure this route as I need to catch this id as queryParams in Component.

Comment: It is some data passed through queryParams. You can get the data using the Router in your AddEditComponent. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5.

Comment: Your route will just be `app/dashboard`

Comment: Actually when clicking, ? is converting to %3f and same with = 
that's why application breaking

Comment: You can simple decode your URL like this. `decodeURI(url)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "app/dashboard",
    component: AddEditComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: ':dashboard_id'
            component: NewComponentId
        }
    ]
  },
];
```

and in your `NewComponentId` you can do something like inside the constructor to catch the id:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((paramMap) => {
        if (paramMap.get('id') !== 'something') {
          // your code
        }
      }),
```

Comment: Actually when clicking, ? is converting to %3f and same with = 
that's why application breaking

Answer (score 0):

**Required Route param**:

```
{path: 'users/:userId', component: UserComponent}
```

and get it from param:

```
constructor(params: RouteParams) {
    var paramId = params.get("id");
}
```

**Optional Route Param**:

```
  { path: '/user', component: UserComponent }
```

its just define the route part and param pass by query string, to read the queryparam:

```
this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
      }
    );
```

you must process the query string for this route: `"app/dashboard?dashboard_id={id}"`

Update:

To set the queryparam in routerlink use it this way:

```
  <a routerLink="/dashboard" [queryParams]="{ dashboard_id: 11 }"
    >another dashboard</a>
```

Comment: Actually when clicking, ? is converting to %3f and same with = 
that's why application breaking

Comment: See the update for passing queryParam @Manish