# How to retrieve a route param using Injector.get(ActivatedRoute)?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. My goal is to have a BaseDetailComponent which can be extended by "detail" components (those which show a single data object's fields). Since the parent class' constructor will receive a service instance and other params, I can't use normal dependency injection in the constructor. Therefore, I need to manually inject the application injector in BaseDetailComponent. I tried the code below. There is an InjectorManager, which has its injector set by the global AppModule. Then BaseDetailComponent retrieves InjectorManager's injector and uses it to get the app's ActivatedRoute instance. But, for some reason, activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id is undefined. And this is my issue. I need to access route params on a class where ordinary constructor dependency injection is unavailable.

```js
export class InjectorManager {

  private static _injector: Injector;

  static get injector(): Injector {
    return this._injector;
  }

  static set injector(value: Injector) {
    this._injector = value;
  }
}

export class AppModule {

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    InjectorManager.injector = injector;
  }
}

@Component({template: ''})
export class BaseDetailComponent {

  protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  constructor(
    private service: BaseService<DtoType>
  ) {
    this.activatedRoute = InjectorManager.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.findById(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id)
      .subscribe(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `activatedRoute.snapshot`, you can try subscribing `activatedRoute.params`.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar question as [Parent components gets empty Params from ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42947133/3136474).

The Angular documentation for [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) states (my emphasis):

> Contains the information about a route **associated with a component** loaded in an outlet.

There is also an [issue of feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023) on Angular's GitHub repo asking for a solution, that states (my emphasis):

> When using a parametrized route which targets a component, **only this component can access those parameters**.

Thus, you are encountering an expected behavior. A [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023#issuecomment-252118964) on that issue states that each component receives its own ActivatedRoute (it does not work as singleton like other injected classes).

On that same GitHub issue, the proposed solution is to inject a [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) and check for the `NavigationEnd` events:

```
router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).forEach(() => {
  // inspect the state on router.routerState
})
```

For a complete example check the file `src/app.ts` on this plunkr provided by [@brandonroberts](https://github.com/brandonroberts) on the GitHub issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/pHd89K?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Firs you can inject `ActivatedRoute` just by placing it in the constructor params.

```js
constructor(
    private service: BaseService<DtoType>,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
) {}
```

Second you have to subscribe to `this.activatedRoute.params` as it can change after the component is initialized:

```js
this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(switchMap(({id}) => this.service.findById(id)).Subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Because BaseDetailComponent is gonna be extended, the constructor cannot have and ActivatedRoute parameter. Otherwise child classes would have to send that, leading to unnecessary repeated code.
For some reason, your suggestion (pipe and switchMap over params Observable) is not working.
`this.activatedRoute.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: Params) => {
          return this.service.findById(params['id']);
        }))
      .subscribe(...`

Comment: Are you sure that you need to retrieve route params? Maybe you mean query params? How does your request look like?

Comment: Stanisalv, thanks for staying with me against this mistery! My request is an HTTP GET against http://localhost:4200/restaurant-detail/3 . I'm trying to retrieve that "3", but I cannot use regular Angular dependenty injection (constructor parameter) because it's about generic components to be extended.

Comment: seems like a route parameter, but what is your routing configuration then?

Answer (score 0):

To get route params subscribe on activatedRoute.params.subscribe((data) => {ur code})
Here the data will contain the params.
suppose your registration is 
path : abc/:id
Then the params will conatin id property.

Comment: I tried, but for some reason it does not work.
`    this.activatedRoute.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: Params) => {
          return this.service.findById(params['id']);
        }))
      .subscribe(`