# Angular injector on extended components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ionic4 and Angular 7.2.2, and I created a base component class to be extended by other components and not have to repeat a lot of things that I always use. In order to avoid the constructor injection, and therefore be forced to pass again the params to the base construtor in th extended class, I am using Injector.get.

The problem that experience is that, when used it this way, a lot of Angular or Ionic injectors that work fine if injected in the child constructor, do not work or return empty values when used in the child, using the parent's reference.

I am sure there is something I am missing out, because upon inspection of the injector when using the one from my base class and the one from the child, they are different.

Uppon execution, and going to: **http://localhost:8101/home/4**

This is the relevant code:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home/4', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home/:id', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'},
];
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BasePage} from '../../tests/base.comp.test';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage extends BasePage {

    constructor(public ar: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();


        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log(`PARAMS FROM inherited activatedRoute-> `, result); // -> outputs {} WRONG!

            }
        );

        ar.params.subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log(`Params from direct injection-> `, result); // -> outputs {id: "4"} Good!
            }
        );


    }

}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HomePage} from './home.page';
import {BasePageModule} from '../../tests/base.test.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BasePageModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomePage
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {
}
```

**base.test.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BasePage} from './base.comp.test';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [BasePage],
    providers: [],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class BasePageModule {
}
```

**base.comp.test.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {AppInjectorTest} from './app.injector.test';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-base',
    template: '',
})
export class BasePage {

    public injector: Injector;
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

    constructor() {
        const injector = AppInjectorTest.getInjector();
        this.activatedRoute = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    }

}
```

**app.injector.test.ts**

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

export class AppInjectorTest {

    private static injector: Injector;

    static setInjector(injector: Injector) {
        AppInjectorTest.injector = injector;
    }

    static getInjector(): Injector {
        return AppInjectorTest.injector;
    }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';

import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {AppInjectorTest} from '../tests/app.injector.test';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private injector: Injector
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();
        AppInjectorTest.setInjector(injector);
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your static injector but it related how  activatedRoute work ,  **ActivatedRoute** contains the information about a route associated with a component. loaded in an **outlet** [doc](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)  , thay whay the injected activatedRoute (component) work instad of base injected activatedrouteservice

> when using a parametrized route which targets a component, only this
>   component can access those parameters.

check this question has similar problem  [How to retrieve a route param using Injector.get(ActivatedRoute)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687242/how-to-retrieve-a-route-param-using-injector-getactivatedroute)

Comment: So it is impossible to extend a basecomponent ans have the reference to activatedRoute automatically from the parent?

Comment: unfortunately so far no m you need to remove the activatedRoute  fromn the base class  

Comment: I asked this about activatedRoute, but I am also having problems with other services like ModalController from ionic. I guess it is the same problem then?

Comment: sorry I have no idea about ionic I hasn't use it   ,so I don't know if it has similar restriction

Comment: The only thing that I know works, is to re-inject the injector into the super, coming from the child. Then, it works. I wanted to avoid that part, for elegance.

Comment: In the child:

constructor(public injector: Injector) {
        super(injector);
(...)

Comment: I marked your answer as valid, but I replied to myself also, in order to make it clear for other people facing the same problem. I am going to to go this way to avoid problems with the idiosincrasy of Angular, even if it is not as smart as having a way to remove the need for injecting in constructors.

Answer (score 2):

For now it seems that the only workaround we want to do this is to re-inject the injector from the child into the parent. It is not as clean as keeping the constructor completely empty, but, at least, you can extend and reuse a lot of logic from a parent component in a neat way.

child.comp.ts (that extends from parent)

```
    constructor(public injector: Injector) {
        super(injector);
    }

(...)
```

parent.comp.ts

```
(...)
    constructor(public injector: Injector) {
         this.activatedRoute = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    }

(...)
```

Comment:  this seam the only way go around this  but it is butter to remove the activatedRoute from the base class and just inject the ActivatedRoute

Comment: Yes. Easy it is. But when I have 20 sub-classes and the parent has to have the upper-hand of the logic, it is a pain to re-throw the activatedRoute up everytime.

Comment: I mean only for the activatedRoute