# Accessing route params in children

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to access params from a child and can't seem to access them.  I have my routes organized as follows:

```
const clientsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'clients',
    component: ClientIndexPage,
    // loadChildren: "./client-index/client-index.module#ClientIndexPageModule",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: 'clients/:id',
    component: ClientDetailPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfilePage
        // loadChildren: './client-detail/profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'finance',
        component: FinancePage
        // loadChildren: './client-detail/finance/finance.module#FinancePageModule'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'profile',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

From `ClientDetailPage` I can access the `:id`, but when I attempt to grab it from the `ProfilePage`, It is inaccessible:

```
// ClientDetailsPage
console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id)
// returns the correct value

// ProfilePage
console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id))
// returns null
console.log(this.route.parent)
//returns null
```

Is there something I am missing?  It might be worth noting that `ClientDetailsPage` and `ProfilePage` both have seperate modules.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42949123/7179294

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to help

Comment: do you have a blitz for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following will access the id param for the activated route.

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

But what is making this not to work is what is considered an activated route.  Only the exact child route that matches is considered the activated route, thus your parent for the route that contains the id param is not in the activated route.

```
// assuming a route like clients/2/profile
{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfilePage
}
```

Good news is you can access the parent object of that route as shown below.

```
// calling route.parent moves us one route up the tree, where id is a param
this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```